# Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scroll

How do I scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript? The scrollbar instantly jumping to the top of the page is desirable too as I'm not looking to achieve smooth scrolling.

Comment: 2019, to avoid “This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning” use my script https://stackoverflow.com/a/57641938/5781320

Comment: SO should delete jQuery answers.

Comment: Try this css `html,body{ scroll-behavior: smooth}` and some script for scroll top `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Answer (score 2670, accepted):

If you don't need the change to animate then you don't need to use any special plugins - I'd just use the native JavaScript `window.scrollTo()` method -- passing in `0, 0` will scroll the page to the top left instantly.

```
window.scrollTo(xCoord, yCoord);
```

Parameters

- xCoord is the pixel along the horizontal axis.
- yCoord is the pixel along the vertical axis.

Comment: That was my point, if you don't need to animate smooth scrolling then you don't need to use jQuery.

Comment: Funny as jeff's comment is honestly for people who just want things to work cross browser 95% of the time should just use jQuery. This is coming from someone who has to write a lot of pure javascript right now because we can't afford the overhead of a library slowing down ad code :(

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. It would be fine if the question was: What script and methods should I use to scroll to the top of the page? Correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147112/how-to-jump-to-top-of-browser-page#answer-4147118

Comment: Working for me in Firefox 40 and Chrome 44 (to address Mikhail's comment)

Comment: and what if I want to scroll to the bottom of the page ?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the page `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);`

Comment: Even if you need to animate. `scrollTo` now takes an options as param: `scrollTo({left: 0, top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})` see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions)

Comment: I tried `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` and I get "undefined"

Comment: could you please help on related question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653046/page-always-autofocus-on-textarea-and-scrolltotop-is-not-working-then

Comment: you have just to add this CSS to get a smooth scroll :)
html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
      }

Answer (score 1470):

If you do want smooth scrolling, try something like this:

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

That will take any `<a>` tag whose `href="#top"` and make it smooth scroll to the top.

Comment: +1. I was just wondering how to do something like this and google lead me here. QUestion though, where is "scrollTop" function in the docs? I just looked but couldn't find it.

Comment: scrollTop is not function, it is a property of the window element

Comment: This does not work correctly when using animate's complete callback, as it will run it twice.

Comment: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); is working

Comment: Do you know why it's necessary to add html & body in the selector?

Comment: @user751564: It's not necessary, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16430109/544283.

Comment: So you've added html to the selector because, although by default it's in body, it may be moved outside, to the html?

Comment: "html" and "body" are both required for browser compatibility, i.e. Chrome v27 scrolls with just "body" and IE8 does not. IE8 scrolls with just "html" but Chrome v27 does not.

Comment: @jalchr Actually, `window.pageYOffset` would be the property of the window e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶  object.

Answer (score 410):

Better solution with smooth animation:

```
// this changes the scrolling behavior to "smooth"
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#Example

Comment: You may still need to polyfill support for the `ScrollOptions` (for certain browsers): https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: I like this solution a lot.

Comment: Can someone test this on Safari or Internet Explorer and see if it's working fine? Thanks

Comment: @FabioMagarelli Its working fine on Safari, not tested on IE. FYI to test it on safari open any page which has scroll and copy paste the above code in Developer Tools -> Console  it will scroll to top verified ( Safari Version 13.0.5).

Comment: This is the best answer. We can use document.body.scrollHeight for the top value if one wants to scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 214):

**Try this to scroll on top**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is the same:  
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
 history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}

Answer (score 118):

You don't need jQuery to do this. A standard HTML  tag will suffice...

```
<div id="jump_to_me">
    blah blah blah
</div>

<a target="#jump_to_me">Click Here To Destroy The World!</a>
```

Comment: +1 This is good if you need to navigate to specific element rather just to the top.

Comment: Use '<a href="#">Top</a>' to jump to the top of the page.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to go when dealing with SPAs

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to make it smooth scroll ?

Comment: This is not going to  work if you call another button by using `getElementById` in the middle of a page.

Answer (score 76):

All of these suggestions work great for various situations. For those who find this page through a search, one can also give [this](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/posts/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/) a try. JQuery, no plug-in, scroll to element.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 59):

smooth scroll, pure javascript:

```
(function smoothscroll(){
    var currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (currentScroll > 0) {
         window.requestAnimationFrame(smoothscroll);
         window.scrollTo (0,currentScroll - (currentScroll/5));
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 46):

```
<script>
$(function(){
   var scroll_pos=(0);          
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:(scroll_pos)}, '2000');
});
</script>
```

Edit:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:(scroll_pos)}, 2000);
```

Another way scroll with top and left margin:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 100, left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Comment: Are you sure duration as string in animate function works?

Comment: You can't use a string for the duration in the `animate` function, instead you should use: 

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:(scroll_pos)}, 2000);`

Comment: What is the point of wrapping 0 in parenthesis? ((0)) will simply evaluate to 0.

Comment: Yes @Jack, you can.

Answer (score 38):

Really strange: This question is active for five years now and there is still no vanilla JavaScript answer to animate the scrolling… So here you go:

```
var scrollToTop = window.setInterval(function() {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if ( pos > 0 ) {
        window.scrollTo( 0, pos - 20 ); // how far to scroll on each step
    } else {
        window.clearInterval( scrollToTop );
    }
}, 16); // how fast to scroll (this equals roughly 60 fps)
```

If you like, you can wrap this in a function and call that via the `onclick` attribute. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osoh6o5a/)

Note: This is a very basic solution and maybe not the most performant one. A very elaborated example can be found here: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a jQuery solution though. so not strange

Comment: Best solution for me. No plugins, no bulky jquery library just straightforward javascript. Kudos

Comment: Man, I also created this same logic XD after 5 years, exactly the same logic, only values are different like, the interval time and that integer which we are using to subtract, can't believe XD. TBH, came here to answer but it's already there so upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 36):

Scroll to **top** of page with **animation**:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Answer (score 33):

```
<script>

  $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
     return false;
  });
</script>
```

in html

```
<a href="#top">go top</a>
```

Answer (score 30):

With `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` is very fast
so i tried the Mark Ursino example, but in Chrome nothing happens
and i found this

```
$('.showPeriodMsgPopup').click(function(){
    //window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $('html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');//IE, FF
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');//chrome, don't know if Safari works
    $('.popupPeriod').fadeIn(1000, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$('.popupPeriod').fadeOut(2000);}, 3000);
    });
});
```

tested all 3 browsers and it works
i'm using blueprint css
this is when a client clicks "Book now" button and doesn't have the rental period selected, slowly moves to the top where the calendars are and opens a dialog div pointing to the 2  fields, after 3sec it fades

Comment: Thanks for pointing out you need to target both html and body. I was only doing it for html and wondering why it didn't work in Chrome.

Comment: The body animation does work in Safari, so I'm updating your answer accordingly.

Comment: "Tested *all 3 browsers*"? Midori, LuaKit and Konqueror, right? :p

Comment: Why not just do $('html', 'body').animate({scrollTop:0}) instead of adding two lines?

Answer (score 30):

If you want to do smooth scrolling, please try this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
     return false;
});
```

Another solution is JavaScript window.scrollTo method :

```
 window.scrollTo(x-value, y-value);
```

Parameters :

- x-value is the pixel along the horizontal axis.
- y-value is the pixel along the vertical axis.

Comment: copycat... see users answers... This is just a compilation of the top 2 answers....

Comment: that is a legitimate way to use stackoverflow - it's more practical to have it in one place. Joel Spolsky used re-use of existing answers as an example of how stackoverflow is supposed to work at one point. If you are interested I can try and find the blog post

Comment: should mention your 1st solution requires jQuery.

Answer (score 26):

Smooth scrolling & animation with vanilla  **Javascript**, without **jQuery**

```js
// Get the element
let topBtn = document.querySelector(".top-btn");

// On Click, Scroll to the page's top, replace 'smooth' with 'instant' if you don't want smooth scrolling
topBtn.onclick = () => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });

// On scroll, Show/Hide the btn with animation
window.onscroll = () => topBtn.style.opacity = window.scrollY > 500 ? 1 : 0;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #111;
  height: 5000px;
  font-size:5rem;
  color: white;
}

.top-btn {
  all: unset;
  font-size:1.5rem; 
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform:scale(1.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<button class="top-btn"></button>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vel sem vel dui sodales cursus. Vivamus nec erat eu nisl facilisis laoreet vel a dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc vel elit eget mauris gravida dictum non at eros. Sed nec massa eu justo interdum fringilla. Fusce nec dolor auctor, tincidunt purus id, feugiat justo. Pellentesque tincidunt, mauris a dapibus eleifend, libero lorem congue elit, eget iaculis odio metus non mi." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vel sem vel dui sodales cursus. Vivamus nec erat eu nisl facilisis laoreet vel a dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc vel elit eget mauris gravida dictum non at eros. Sed nec massa eu justo interdum fringilla. Fusce nec dolor auctor, tincidunt purus id, feugiat justo. Pellentesque tincidunt, mauris a dapibus eleifend, libero lorem congue elit, eget iaculis odio metus non mi." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vel sem vel dui sodales cursus. Vivamus nec erat eu nisl facilisis laoreet vel a dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc vel elit eget mauris gravida dictum non at eros. Sed nec massa eu justo interdum fringilla. Fusce nec dolor auctor, tincidunt purus id, feugiat justo. Pellentesque tincidunt, mauris a dapibus eleifend, libero lorem congue elit, eget iaculis odio metus non mi." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vel sem vel dui sodales cursus. Vivamus nec erat eu nisl facilisis laoreet vel a dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc vel elit eget mauris gravida dictum non at eros. Sed nec massa eu justo interdum fringilla. Fusce nec dolor auctor, tincidunt purus id, feugiat justo. Pellentesque tincidunt, mauris a dapibus eleifend, libero lorem congue elit, eget iaculis odio metus non mi." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vel sem vel dui sodales cursus. Vivamus nec erat eu nisl facilisis laoreet vel a dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc vel elit eget mauris gravida dictum non at eros. Sed nec massa eu justo interdum fringilla. Fusce nec dolor auctor, tincidunt purus id, feugiat justo. Pellentesque tincidunt, mauris a dapibus eleifend, libero lorem congue elit, eget iaculis odio metus non mi."</p>
```

With **React.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => setIsVisible(window.scrollY > 500);
  const scrollToTop = () => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });


  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button
      style={{
        all: 'unset',
        fontSize: '1.5rem',
        position: 'fixed',
        right: '20px',
        bottom: '20px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transform: 'scale(1.8)',
        opacity: isVisible ? 1 : 0,
        transition: '0.3s',
      }}
      onClick={scrollToTop}
    >
      
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 25):

A [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145297/1015595) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981461/1015595) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278290/1015595) recommend selecting both the html and body tags for cross-browser compatibility, like so:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
```

This can trip you up though if you're counting on your callback running only once. It will in fact run twice because you've selected two elements.

If that is a problem for you, you can do something like this:

```
function scrollToTop(callback) {
    if ($('html').scrollTop()) {
        $('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
        return;
    }

    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
}
```

The reason this works is in Chrome `$('html').scrollTop()` returns 0, but not in other browsers such as Firefox.

If you don't want to wait for the animation to complete in the case that the scrollbar is already at the top, try this:

```
function scrollToTop(callback) {
    if ($('html').scrollTop()) {
        $('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
        return;
    }

    if ($('body').scrollTop()) {
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
        return;
    }

    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The old `#top` can do the trick

```
document.location.href = "#top";
```

Works fine in FF, IE and Chrome

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to make it smooth scroll ?

Comment: you should avoid navigation based solutions, see comments on Sriramajeyam's answer.

Answer (score 22):

**This will work:**

**`window.scrollTo(0, 0);`**

Comment: This was the best answer

Answer (score 20):

```js
$(".scrolltop").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.section{
 height:400px;
}
.section1{
  background-color: #333;
}
.section2{
  background-color: red;
}
.section3{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.section4{
  background-color: green;
}
.scrolltop{
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Scroll top demo</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="section section1"></div>
<div class="section section2"></div>
<div class="section section3"></div>
<div class="section section4"></div>
<a class="scrolltop">Scroll top</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Comment: Explain your answer!

Comment: In web page any user will click on scroll top button then then page will scroll top top with animation.

Comment: Why animate() instead of jquery scroll()?

Comment: What he is stating is true, and I believe it's a great answer as that version of jQuery already comes with support for scrolling .. if you open the JS file you will find the explanation there.. just need to target the class // Create scrollLeft and scrollTop methods
jQuery.each( { scrollLeft: "pageXOffset", scrollTop: "pageYOffset" }, function( method, prop ) {

Answer (score 19):

Non-jQuery solution / pure JavaScript:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Answer (score 17):

The equivalent solution in **TypeScript** may be as the following

```
   window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
```

Comment: Your snippet has nothing to do with TypeScript and work perfectly fine in Javascript.

Comment: Your code Works perfect

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(window).scrollTop(100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

`$(document).scrollTop(0);` also works.

Comment: Note that when you don't use Firefox this won't work. You get an error when only giving one argument (Error: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.scrollTo]).

Answer (score 14):

Pure JavaScript solution:

```
function scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

I write an animated solution on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Hassanvand/pen/LRoaQL)

Also, you can try another solution with CSS [`scroll-behavior: smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) property.

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    html {
        scroll-behavior: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this code:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("div").offset().top
}, time);
```

**div =>** Dom Element where you want to move scroll.

**time =>** milliseconds, define the speed of the scroll.

Answer (score 8):

You dont need JQuery. Simply you can call the script

```
window.location = '#'
```

on click of the "Go to top" button

Sample demo:

[output.jsbin.com/fakumo#](http://output.jsbin.com/fakumo)

PS: Don't use this approach, when you are using modern libraries like angularjs. That might broke the URL hashbang.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the best solution since you are changing location physically in that case instead of scrolling the page. That might cause issues if location is important (in case of using Angular routing or so)

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza is correct. While it *may* work in simple cases, I would not recommend this solution. Location is becoming increasingly important and single-page apps extensively use the hash to handle navigation. You would immediately introduce a side-effect bug when either adding hash based navigation after this or this to hash based navigation.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use JQuery inbuilt function scrollTop :

```
$('html, body').scrollTop(0);//For scrolling to top

$("body").scrollTop($("body")[0].scrollHeight);//For scrolling to bottom
```

Short and simple!

Comment: You're just missing the link [to the doc](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop-value)

Answer (score 8):

### Motivation

This simple solution works natively and implements a smooth scroll to any position.

It avoids using anchor links (those with `#`) that, in my opinion, are useful if you want to link to a section, but are not so comfortable in some situations, specially when pointing to top which could lead to two different URLs pointing to the same location (*http://www.example.org* and *http://www.example.org/#*).

### Solution

Put an *id* to the tag you want to scroll to, for example your first *section*, which answers this question, but the *id* could be placed everywhere in the page.

```
<body>
  <section id="top">
    <!-- your content -->
  </section>
  <div id="another"><!-- more content --></div>
```

Then as a button you can use a link, just edit the *onclick* attribute with a code like this.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' })">Click me</a>
```

Where the argument of `document.getElementById` is the *id* of the tag you want to scroll to after click.

Comment: Thanks you! is great solution

Comment: @HugoStivenLagunaRueda you welcome, I found it on MDN, so thanks to Mozilla. It is awesome how many things are already there, supported natively. I love vanilla JS.

Answer (score 8):

`document.getElementById("elem").scrollIntoView();`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only one that worked for me, strange though. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want smooth scrolling, you can cheat and stop the smooth scrolling animation pretty much as soon as you start it... like so:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "1");              
          $('html, body').stop(true, true);

          //Anything else you want to do in the same action goes here

          return false;                              
      });
  });
```

I've no idea whether it's recommended/allowed, but it works :)

When would you use this? I'm not sure, but perhaps when you want to use one click to animate one thing with Jquery, but do another without animation? ie open a slide-in admin login panel at the top of the page, and instantly jump to the top to see it.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use this script for scroll to top direct.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        ($('body').scrollTop(0));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

## You can use javascript's built in function `scrollTo`:

```js
function scroll() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scroll">Scroll</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use a target from your link, such as #someid, where #someid is the div's id.

Or, you could use any number of scrolling plugins that make this more elegant.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo is an example.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers above will work in SharePoint 2016.

It has to be done like this : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195870/

```
var w = document.getElementById("s4-workspace");
w.scrollTop = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using JS as in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5bNmH/1/

Add the "Go to top" button in your page footer:

```
<footer>
    <hr />
    <p>Just some basic footer text.</p>
    <!-- Go to top Button -->
    <a href="#" class="go-top">Go Top</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function scrolltop() {

    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 500;

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('#back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            jQuery('#back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });

    jQuery('#back-to-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Answer (score 3):

Active all Browser. Good luck

```
var process;
        var delay = 50; //milisecond scroll top
        var scrollPixel = 20; //pixel U want to change after milisecond
        //Fix Undefine pageofset when using IE 8 below;
        function getPapeYOfSet() {
            var yOfSet = (typeof (window.pageYOffset) === "number") ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            return yOfSet;
        }



        function backToTop() {
            process = setInterval(function () {
                var yOfSet = getPapeYOfSet();
                if (yOfSet === 0) {
                    clearInterval(process);
                } else {
                    window.scrollBy(0, -scrollPixel);
                }
            }, delay);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<script>
  $(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
    var href =$(this).attr("href");
   $('body, html').animate({
     scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
     }, 1000)
  });
 });
 </script>﻿
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution using simple css just put css `scroll-behavior:smooth` on `html and body` as i have applied in css. that's it

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0)
}
```

```css
html,body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
a{
  background-color: red;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin:10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<a>Scroll to Top</a>
```

I Hope this will help you a lot. Please do let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to scroll to any element with an ID, try this:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 700, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});``
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just Try, no need other plugin / frameworks**

```js
document.getElementById("jarscroolbtn").addEventListener("click", jarscrollfunction);

function jarscrollfunction() {
  var body = document.body; // For Safari
  var html = document.documentElement; // Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera 
  body.scrollTop = 0; 
  html.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="jarscroolbtn">Scroll contents</button>
```

```css
html, body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is ***no need to javascript***, event if you wanted to animate the scroll action!

**CSS:**

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body>
     <a id="top"></a>
     <!-- your document -->
     <a href="#top">Jump to top of page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP asked for javascript and did not state the causing event is a clck on an anchor.

Comment: Edit your answer to specifically start with "If the scrolling is always triggered by a click on an anchor, then..."

Answer (score 2):

### Back to Top with AplineJS and TailwindCSS:

```
<button
    x-cloak
    x-data="{scroll : false}"
    @scroll.window="document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20 ? scroll = true : scroll = false"
    x-show="scroll" @click="window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})"
    type="button"
    data-mdb-ripple="true"
    data-mdb-ripple-color="light"
    class="fixed inline-block p-3 text-xs font-medium leading-tight text-white uppercase transition duration-150 ease-in-out bg-blue-600 rounded-full shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg bottom-5 right-5"
    id="btn-back-to-top"
    x-transition.opacity
>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-4 h-4" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.293 9.707a1 1 0 010-1.414l6-6a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L11 5.414V17a1 1 0 11-2 0V5.414L4.707 9.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When top scroll is top less than limit bottom and bottom to top scroll Header is Sticky. Below See Fiddle Example.

```
var lastScroll = 0;

$(document).ready(function($) {

$(window).scroll(function(){

 setTimeout(function() { 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > lastScroll) {

        $("header").removeClass("menu-sticky");

    } 
    if (scroll == 0) {
    $("header").removeClass("menu-sticky");

    }
    else if (scroll < lastScroll - 5) {


        $("header").addClass("menu-sticky");

    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
    },0);
    });
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/memdumusaib/d52xcLm3/

Answer (score 1):

### Shortest

```
location='#'
```

This solution is improvement of [pollirrata answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27220838/860099) and have some drawback: no smooth scroll and change page location, but is shortest

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling to the element and element being at the top of the page

```
WebElement tempElement=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Excel']"));

            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", tempElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of scroll to (using html is much more efficient but here is how to do it with JavaScript):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
      window.scrollTo({
       left: 0,
       top: 0,
})})
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    const scrollHeight = window.pageYOffset;
    if (scrollHeight > 500) {
        btn.classList.add('show-link');
    } else {
        btn.classList.remove('show-link');
    }
});
```

```css
.section {
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    height: 90vh;
}
.btn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3rem;
    right: 3rem;
    background: blue;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
.show-link {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 100;
}

.title h2 {
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
    <section class="section">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>Section Two</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section  class="section">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>Section Three</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <a class="btn">
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code, surely it will be helpful. :)

```
document.querySelector('.sample-modal .popup-cta').scrollIntoView(true);
document.querySelector('.sample-modal').style.scrollPadding = '50px'; //to move to the top when scrolled up.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
document.documentElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
```

Comment: I achieved using React useRef, `theRef.current.props.node.ownerDocument.documentElement` and so on...

Answer (score -1):

Funnily enough, most of these did not work for me AT ALL, so I used jQuery-ScrollTo.js with this:

```
wrapper.find(".jumpToTop").click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').ScrollTo({
        duration: 0,
        offsetTop: -1*$('#container').offset().top
    });
});
```

And it worked. `$(document).scrollTop()` was returning `0`, and this one actually worked instead.