# Return to top of the page when clicking back

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have the following question/problem:

On this page http://www.projectyou.gr/gp/?page_id=5 there are 3 tabs
*[It's all in Greek but I hope you will understand]*
Each tab contains links to articles.
When you click on an article and then press the back button on the browser it comes back
to the selected tab AND scrolls to the article you clicked.
As much as I like this behavior it is not what I want in this case.
I would like the user, when returning to the page, always go to the top.

What is the best way to achieve this.
Does it have to do with the fact that I'm using jQuery tabs and the code that I have
for returning to the previously selected tab causes to jump to previously clicked anchor??

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what top are you saying?... when I click a tab, my back button is not even click-able...

Comment: Click on an article that is down to the bottom of the page.
This will get you to another page.
If you click back then you return to the bottom of the page.
I would like to prevent that and always return to top of page.
Hope that helps. Thanks for the quick respond :_)

Comment: now, when I press back button, it brings me to tab Εκπαίδευση. Am I with you at this? even if I was not on that tab before I clicked a link...

Comment: yes this is correct ... when clicking the back button it goes to the first tab. That is another thing am working on. Any suggestions would be great. It is a bit confusing working with jQuery tabs when it comes to history and anchor tags.

Answer (score 2):

how about adding something such as this to your document ready handler (I realize you may already have one, so just appending the scrollTo might do it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

like in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. Just did it. However it seems like it goes down and then up. There is a small latency ... it would be great if we could find a solution to prevent that behavior. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: well... instead of scrolling at the end of the ready handler, you could try and sneak it in a "normal" <script> block, although I really don't know if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 500 );
```

which scrolls it in an animated way,
The 500 is the speed in milliseconds

the 0 is how from from the top of the page,

if you wanted to scroll to the top of an element you could replace it with

```
var offset = $('element').offset();
var top = offset.top;
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: top}, 500 )
```

;