# how to make page up link

Tags: jquery

how to make page up link

i have to make link in my site when user click it shows a top view of site "i mean it goes to header of my site"

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How do I scroll to the top of the page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1144805/230354).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `#` as "URL":

```
<a href="#"> Go Up <a/>
```

No JavaScript required.

Comment: You mean it should scroll to the top?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('a#top').click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop' : 0},1000);
    });
});
```

Test it here : **http://jsbin.com/ucati4**

Answer (score 0):

What about giving your header some id (e.g., 'header') and making a link to it (`<a href="#header">go up</a>`)? Simple enough.