# How do I go to the top of the page on clicking a button , by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how do I go to the top of a webpage onclicking a button , by using jquery?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scroll to the top of the page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the search function next time.

`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");`