# Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a simple, cross-browser "scroll to top" animation I can apply to a link. I don't want to require a JS library such as jQuery/Moo, etc.

```
// jQuery Equivilant to convert to pure JS...
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 400);
```

I'm a perfect case for someone who should have learned JS 100% before jumping into a library. :(

Comment: +1 for *not* wanting to use jQuery, with a valid reason :) For inspiration, you can have a look at the source code of these libraries, e.g. [jquery-1.7.1.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js).

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery

Comment: @RobW what do you have against jQuery?

Comment: @seand JavaScript is not jQuery, but jQuery is JavaScript. If one (such as the OP) wants to learn JavaScript, (s)he should not touch any bloated libraries, unless they got the idea how to write the same code in JavaScript.

Comment: @RobW using a library like jQuery helps abstract away the cross-browser differences, so i would see it as crucial to web development; you shouldn't need to know those differences if a perfectly good implementation exists and is freely available

Comment: @seand and that is how we produce crappy coders. They don't understand the language, but can spawn unlimited amounts of jQuery code, because they know it. This leads to hacks like storing everything in DOM (because sometimes they don't even know what variable is, other than `var something = $(...)`), recreating gazillion of objects in every function (they know variables, but don't know that `var veryBigObject = {...}` with few hundred of properties at the top of the function is going to murder performance). And **very often** they don't even know the language's name is Javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Just wanted to share an alternative (no intervals/timeouts) solution in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625387/smooth-scrolling-in-javascript/26625940#26625940

Comment: not using jquery for only this is fine, but if you get 10 more things that you don't want to use jquery then you really are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590388/5626568

Answer (score 141):

```
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

Demo:

```js
function runScroll() {
  scrollTo(document.body, 0, 600);
}
var scrollme;
scrollme = document.querySelector("#scrollme");
scrollme.addEventListener("click",runScroll,false)

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
  if (duration <= 0) return;
  var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
  var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    if (element.scrollTop == to) return;
    scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<p>Very long page.Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page.  Very long page.Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page.  Very long page.Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page.  Very long page.Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page.  Very long page.Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page. Very long page.
</p>
<button id=scrollme type="button">To the top</button>
```

Comment: `document.documentElement` instead of `document.body` (unless you set CSS: `body{height:100%;}`). Working demo using this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/S5ALP/1/

Comment: @RobW Your addition doesn't work here in Google Chrome @ Ubuntu Linux

Comment: it does in Firefox 9.0, Ubuntu too :). Your code failed in Firefox, but worked in Chrome, my code failed in Chrome, but worked in FF.

Comment: That should be `if (duration <= 0) return;`

Comment: Modifying it to use `top.window.scroll(0, value)` instead of `element.scrollTop = value` made it work in both Chrome and Firefox (Ubuntu). :)

Comment: @Shomz Do you have a demo?

Comment: @TimWolla Just a modified version that scrolls to the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/nQrq9/

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]')` to get all the relevant links on the page

Comment: this does not work on latest mac firefox, but works on latest mac chrome.

Comment: Fixed the answer with @JonKoops improvement. If `duration` was 0, it would `scrollTo` the top.

Comment: For anyone struggling with cross-browser compatibility with the latest Chrome and FF, this should do the trick: `window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0`, as [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633515/1048032)

Comment: is there an easy way to add some easing?

Comment: Best answer so far. Need not go for unnecessary scroll-to-top plugins. Plain Vanila :)

Comment: Just throwing out that this snippet doesn't work on chrome version 69.0.3497.100, which is the newest version as of today.

Answer (score 115):

looks like there's a lot of solutions already. anyway, here's another one, uses easing equations..

```
// first add raf shim
// http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

// main function
function scrollToY(scrollTargetY, speed, easing) {
    // scrollTargetY: the target scrollY property of the window
    // speed: time in pixels per second
    // easing: easing equation to use

    var scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        scrollTargetY = scrollTargetY || 0,
        speed = speed || 2000,
        easing = easing || 'easeOutSine',
        currentTime = 0;

    // min time .1, max time .8 seconds
    var time = Math.max(.1, Math.min(Math.abs(scrollY - scrollTargetY) / speed, .8));

    // easing equations from https://github.com/danro/easing-js/blob/master/easing.js
    var easingEquations = {
            easeOutSine: function (pos) {
                return Math.sin(pos * (Math.PI / 2));
            },
            easeInOutSine: function (pos) {
                return (-0.5 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * pos) - 1));
            },
            easeInOutQuint: function (pos) {
                if ((pos /= 0.5) < 1) {
                    return 0.5 * Math.pow(pos, 5);
                }
                return 0.5 * (Math.pow((pos - 2), 5) + 2);
            }
        };

    // add animation loop
    function tick() {
        currentTime += 1 / 60;

        var p = currentTime / time;
        var t = easingEquations[easing](p);

        if (p < 1) {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);

            window.scrollTo(0, scrollY + ((scrollTargetY - scrollY) * t));
        } else {
            console.log('scroll done');
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollTargetY);
        }
    }

    // call it once to get started
    tick();
}

// scroll it!
scrollToY(0, 1500, 'easeInOutQuint');
```

Comment: Glad someone is using `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: Should be voted up and selected as the answer. This is the only one that works cross browser

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is not compatible with all browsers spsly some mobiles , so its not a dynamic solution , see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @SUB-HDR at the top of the snippet there is a shim for `requestAnimationFrame` that should take care of any browser incompatibility

Comment: The animations become very laggy when a page has a section with a lot of images on Firefox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396100/firefox-scroll-is-very-laggy-compared-to-chrome-and-safari?noredirect=1#comment99396850_56396100

Answer (score 90):

```
window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Got it from an article about [Smooth Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

If needed, there are some [polyfills](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/) available.

Comment: Almost downvoted because I thought this was a jQuery solution. That article is confusingly categorized!

Also, I wanted to point out that `scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})` exists as well, and may do what people need for this sort of problem.

Comment: This throws an error in latest Chrome `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`

Comment: @rorymorris89 works for me on Chrome Version `61.0.3163.100`

Comment: @Sgnl can confirm this is now fixed. Good old Chrome updates breaking things :)

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more votes, a simple scroll to top without 100000 lines of code! Thank you!

Comment: This answer must be marked as the accepted one. A built-in approach without any use of custom transitioning functions, why not!? Thank you!

Comment: Great answer dawg

Comment: Yes this awesome. Do not need additional effort. So awesome.

Comment: Notice that this approach, UNFORTUNATELY, lacks very important features - [1] [You can't control the speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729223/863110). [2]. [There is no option to wait for animation end](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3744).

Answer (score 72):

I modified TimWolla's answer to use quadratic in-out easing ( a little smoother :). Here is an example in action: [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62MTU/15/). Easing functions are available here: [Robert Penner's Easing functions](http://robertpenner.com/easing/)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function () {
    scrollTo(document.body, 0, 1250);   
}

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        increment = 20;

    var animateScroll = function(elapsedTime) {        
        elapsedTime += increment;
        var position = easeInOut(elapsedTime, start, change, duration);                        
        element.scrollTop = position; 
        if (elapsedTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                animateScroll(elapsedTime);
            }, increment);
        }
    };

    animateScroll(0);
}

function easeInOut(currentTime, start, change, duration) {
    currentTime /= duration / 2;
    if (currentTime < 1) {
        return change / 2 * currentTime * currentTime + start;
    }
    currentTime -= 1;
    return -change / 2 * (currentTime * (currentTime - 2) - 1) + start;
}
```

Comment: You code doesn't work in firefox. Is there solution for this?

Comment: @Milos Just use "scrollTo(document.documentElement, 0, 1250);" instead of "scrollTo(document.body, 0, 1250);" and it should work both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Why you are using Math? Without Math it is working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bcliks/h2hgb6z4/)

Comment: @Daniel `document. documentElement` does not work in Chrome.

Comment: @bCliks, it's an easing method

Comment: This code makes the whole page reload in some browsers (Chromium and Opera, at least), as opposed to, for instance, [this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

Comment: Really like the easing!

Answer (score 29):

Without JQuery code, Hope this will help you.

```
function TopscrollTo() {
if(window.scrollY!=0)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.scrollTo(0,window.scrollY-30);
        TopscrollTo();
    }, 100);
   }
}
```

call this **TopscrollTo() function** on button click event or on any other element/event which you want.

Answer (score 22):

I modified the code of @TimWolla to add more options and a some movement functions.
Also, added support to crossbrowser with *document.body.scrollTop* and *document.documentElement.scrollTop*

```
// scroll to top
scrollTo(0, 1000);

// Element to move, time in ms to animate
function scrollTo(element, duration) {
    var e = document.documentElement;
    if(e.scrollTop===0){
        var t = e.scrollTop;
        ++e.scrollTop;
        e = t+1===e.scrollTop--?e:document.body;
    }
    scrollToC(e, e.scrollTop, element, duration);
}

// Element to move, element or px from, element or px to, time in ms to animate
function scrollToC(element, from, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    if(typeof from === "object")from=from.offsetTop;
    if(typeof to === "object")to=to.offsetTop;

    scrollToX(element, from, to, 0, 1/duration, 20, easeOutCuaic);
}

function scrollToX(element, xFrom, xTo, t01, speed, step, motion) {
    if (t01 < 0 || t01 > 1 || speed<= 0) {
        element.scrollTop = xTo;
        return;
    }
    element.scrollTop = xFrom - (xFrom - xTo) * motion(t01);
    t01 += speed * step;

    setTimeout(function() {
        scrollToX(element, xFrom, xTo, t01, speed, step, motion);
    }, step);
}
function easeOutCuaic(t){
    t--;
    return t*t*t+1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/forestrf/tPQSv/

Minified version:
http://jsfiddle.net/forestrf/tPQSv/139/

```
// c = element to scroll to or top position in pixels
// e = duration of the scroll in ms, time scrolling
// d = (optative) ease function. Default easeOutCuaic
function scrollTo(c,e,d){d||(d=easeOutCuaic);var a=document.documentElement;if(0===a.scrollTop){var b=a.scrollTop;++a.scrollTop;a=b+1===a.scrollTop--?a:document.body}b=a.scrollTop;0>=e||("object"===typeof b&&(b=b.offsetTop),"object"===typeof c&&(c=c.offsetTop),function(a,b,c,f,d,e,h){function g(){0>f||1<f||0>=d?a.scrollTop=c:(a.scrollTop=b-(b-c)*h(f),f+=d*e,setTimeout(g,e))}g()}(a,b,c,0,1/e,20,d))};
function easeOutCuaic(t){
    t--;
    return t*t*t+1;
}
```

Comment: And What's the point of doing `1 / duration` when you call scrollToX for the first time?

Comment: t01 is a time that is incremented from 0 to 1. If it reaches 1, the croll ends. I did this 2 years ago, I don't remember everything, sorry.

Answer (score 17):

No one mentioned the CSS property  [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

CSS

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

JS

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

Comment: This works amazing! Not supported in all browsers, but that's okay since it falls back nicely.

Comment: Jesus, where has this been all my life?

Comment: Up, up, up, up! :)

Answer (score 11):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24559613/1942069):

```
function scroll(y, duration) {

    var initialY = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var baseY = (initialY + y) * 0.5;
    var difference = initialY - baseY;
    var startTime = performance.now();

    function step() {
        var normalizedTime = (performance.now() - startTime) / duration;
        if (normalizedTime > 1) normalizedTime = 1;

        window.scrollTo(0, baseY + difference * Math.cos(normalizedTime * Math.PI));
        if (normalizedTime < 1) window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

This should allow you to smoothly scroll (cosine function) from anywhere to the specified "y".

Answer (score 11):

There is actually a pure javascript way to accomplish this without using `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` or jQuery.

In short, find the element in the scrollView that you want to scroll to, and use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

`el.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});`

Here is a [plunkr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: Best answer: one line of code, the shortest one and effective ;)

Comment: Note that passing the `scrollIntoViewOption` does not have cross-browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 9):

**PURE JAVASCRIPT SCROLLER CLASS**

This is an old question but I thought I could answer with some fancy stuff and some more options to play with if you want to have a bit more control over the animation.

Cross-browser

Copy/Paste ready solution (You only need CSS and JS)

3 animate modes: **["normal"|"linear"|false]**

Customize your animation with available settings - make it snappy or fluent

Double click to skip animation

Every next single click adds initial speed

Stop scroll animation by draging down the scroll bar

Stop scroll animation by mouse wheel down

Animated button fade-in-out on scroll

Here it is a pure JS Class to take care of the scrolling for you:

**SEE DEMO AT** [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/GlupiJas/pen/ZWewPO) OR **GO TO THE BOTTOM AND RUN THE SINPET**

```
// ------------------- USE EXAMPLE ---------------------
// *Set options
var options = {
  'showButtonAfter': 200, // show button after scroling down this amount of px
  'animate': "linear", // [false|normal|linear] - for false no aditional settings are needed

  'normal': { // applys only if [animate: normal] - set scroll loop distanceLeft/steps|ms
    'steps': 20, // the more steps per loop the slower animation gets
    'ms': 10 // the less ms the quicker your animation gets
  }, 
  'linear': { // applys only if [animate: linear] - set scroll px|ms
    'px': 30, // the more px the quicker your animation gets
    'ms': 10 // the less ms the quicker your animation gets
  }, 
};


// *Create new Scroller and run it.
var scroll = new Scroller(options);
scroll.init();
```

FULL CLASS SCRIPT + USE EXAMPLE:

```js
// PURE JAVASCRIPT (OOP)

function Scroller(options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.button = null;
  this.stop = false;
}

Scroller.prototype.constructor = Scroller;

Scroller.prototype.createButton = function() {

  this.button = document.createElement('button');
  this.button.classList.add('scroll-button');
  this.button.classList.add('scroll-button--hidden');
  this.button.textContent = "^";
  document.body.appendChild(this.button);
}

Scroller.prototype.init = function() {
  this.createButton();
  this.checkPosition();
  this.click();
  this.stopListener();
}

Scroller.prototype.scroll = function() {
  if (this.options.animate == false || this.options.animate == "false") {
    this.scrollNoAnimate();
    return;
  }
  if (this.options.animate == "normal") {
    this.scrollAnimate();
    return;
  }
  if (this.options.animate == "linear") {
    this.scrollAnimateLinear();
    return;
  }
}
Scroller.prototype.scrollNoAnimate = function() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
Scroller.prototype.scrollAnimate = function() {
  if (this.scrollTop() > 0 && this.stop == false) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.scrollAnimate();
      window.scrollBy(0, (-Math.abs(this.scrollTop()) / this.options.normal['steps']));
    }.bind(this), (this.options.normal['ms']));
  }
}
Scroller.prototype.scrollAnimateLinear = function() {
  if (this.scrollTop() > 0 && this.stop == false) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.scrollAnimateLinear();
      window.scrollBy(0, -Math.abs(this.options.linear['px']));
    }.bind(this), this.options.linear['ms']);
  }
}

Scroller.prototype.click = function() {

  this.button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.scroll();
  }.bind(this), false);

  this.button.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.scrollNoAnimate();
  }.bind(this), false);

}

Scroller.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.button.classList.add("scroll-button--hidden");
}

Scroller.prototype.show = function() {
  this.button.classList.remove("scroll-button--hidden");
}

Scroller.prototype.checkPosition = function() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    if (this.scrollTop() > this.options.showButtonAfter) {
      this.show();
    } else {
      this.hide();
    }
  }.bind(this), false);
}

Scroller.prototype.stopListener = function() {

  // stop animation on slider drag
  var position = this.scrollTop();
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    if (this.scrollTop() > position) {
      this.stopTimeout(200);
    } else {
      //...
    }
    position = this.scrollTop();
  }.bind(this, position), false);

  // stop animation on wheel scroll down
  window.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) this.stopTimeout(200);
  }.bind(this), false);
}

Scroller.prototype.stopTimeout = function(ms) {
  this.stop = true;
  // console.log(this.stop); //
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.stop = false;
    console.log(this.stop); //
  }.bind(this), ms);
}

Scroller.prototype.scrollTop = function() {
  var curentScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  return curentScrollTop;
}



// ------------------- USE EXAMPLE ---------------------
// *Set options
var options = {
  'showButtonAfter': 200, // show button after scroling down this amount of px
  'animate': "normal", // [false|normal|linear] - for false no aditional settings are needed

  'normal': { // applys only if [animate: normal] - set scroll loop distanceLeft/steps|ms
    'steps': 20, // the more steps per loop the slower animation gets
    'ms': 10 // the less ms the quicker your animation gets
  },
  'linear': { // applys only if [animate: linear] - set scroll px|ms
    'px': 30, // the more px the quicker your animation gets
    'ms': 10 // the less ms the quicker your animation gets
  },
};
// *Create new Scroller and run it.
var scroll = new Scroller(options);
scroll.init();
```

```css
/* CSS */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 25%;
}
.scroll-button {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  visibility: visible;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.2s;
  -o-transition: all 1.2s;
}
.scroll-button:hover {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.scroll-button--hidden {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<h1>Scroll down by 200px for button to appear</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Cross-browser</li>
  <li>Copy/Paste solution</li>
  <li>3 animate modes: <b>["normal"|"linear"|false]</b></li>
  <li>Customize your aniamtion with aveilable settings - make it snapy or fluent</li>
  <li>Double click to skip animation</li>
  <li>Every next single click adds initial speed</li>
  <li>Stop scroll animation by draging down the scroll bar</li>
  <li>Stop scroll animation by mouse wheel down</li>
  <li>Animated button fade-in-out on scroll</li>
</ul>

<br />
<br />
<pre>
// ------------------- USE EXAMPLE ---------------------
// *Set options
var options = {
  'showButtonAfter': 200, // show button after scroling down this amount of px
  'animate': "normal", // [false|normal|linear] - for false no aditional settings are needed
  
  'normal': { // applys only if [animate: normal] - set scroll loop distanceLeft/steps|ms
    'steps': 20, // the more steps the slower animation gets
    'ms': 20 // the less ms the quicker your animation gets
  }, 
  'linear': { // applys only if [animate: linear] - set scroll px|ms
    'px': 55, // the more px the quicker your animation gets
    'ms': 10 // the less ms the quicker your animation gets
  }, 
};

// *Create new Scroller and run it.
var scroll = new Scroller(options);
scroll.init();
</pre>
<br />
<br />
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae molestiae illo nobis quo autem molestias voluptatum quam, amet ipsum debitis, iure animi illum soluta eaque qui perspiciatis harum, sequi nesciunt.</span><span>Quisquam nesciunt aspernatur a possimus pariatur enim architecto. Hic aperiam sit repellat doloremque vel est soluta et assumenda dolore, sint sapiente porro, quam impedit. Sint praesentium quas excepturi, voluptatem dicta!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, porro nisi molestias minima corrupti tempore, dolorum fugiat ipsam dicta doloremque accusamus atque consequatur iusto natus, mollitia distinctio odit dolor tempora.</span><span>Perferendis a in laudantium accusantium, dolorum eius placeat velit porro similique, eum cumque veniam neque aspernatur architecto suscipit rem laboriosam voluptates laborum? Voluptates tempora necessitatibus animi nostrum quod, maxime odio.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil accusantium, itaque corporis repellat pariatur soluta officia perspiciatis in reprehenderit facere, incidunt saepe excepturi. Inventore atque ex illo, ipsam at deserunt.</span><span>Laborum inventore officia, perspiciatis cumque magni consequatur iste accusantium soluta, nesciunt blanditiis voluptatibus adipisci laudantium mollitia minus quia necessitatibus voluptates. Minima unde quos impedit necessitatibus aspernatur minus maiores ipsa eligendi!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate nesciunt, explicabo similique, quo maxime modi, aliquid, voluptatibus repellendus dolorum placeat mollitia ea dicta quia laboriosam alias dignissimos ipsam tenetur. Nulla.</span><span>Vel maiores necessitatibus odio voluptate debitis, error in accusamus nulla, eum, nemo et ea commodi. Autem numquam at, consequatur temporibus. Mollitia placeat nobis blanditiis impedit distinctio! Ad, incidunt fugiat sed.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam voluptatum, odio quam omnis iste laudantium, itaque architecto, eos ullam debitis delectus sapiente nemo autem reprehenderit. Dolorem quidem facere ipsam! Nisi.</span><span>Vitae quaerat modi voluptatibus ratione numquam? Sapiente aliquid officia pariatur quibusdam aliquam id expedita non recusandae, cumque deserunt asperiores. Corrupti et doloribus aspernatur ipsum asperiores, ipsa unde corporis commodi reiciendis?</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima adipisci minus iste, nesciunt itaque quisquam quidem voluptatum assumenda rerum aliquid, excepturi voluptatem tempora. Possimus ratione alias a error vel, rem.</span><span>Officia esse error accusantium veritatis ad, et sit animi? Recusandae mollitia odit tenetur ad cumque maiores eligendi blanditiis nobis hic tempora obcaecati consequatur commodi totam, debitis, veniam, ducimus molestias ut.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quibusdam, tempora cupiditate quaerat tempore ullam delectus voluptates optio eum placeat provident consequatur iure reprehenderit vero quae sapiente architecto earum nemo.</span><span>Quis molestias sint fuga doloribus, necessitatibus nulla. Esse ipsa, itaque asperiores. Tempora a sequi nobis cumque incidunt aspernatur, pariatur rem voluptatibus. Atque veniam magnam, ea laudantium ipsum reprehenderit sapiente repellendus.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, pariatur at explicabo aliquid repudiandae vero eum quasi totam voluptates iusto unde ad repellendus ipsam et voluptatem hic adipisci! Vero, nobis!</span><span>Consequatur eligendi quo quas omnis architecto dolorum aperiam doloremque labore, explicabo enim incidunt vitae saepe, quod soluta illo odit provident amet beatae quasi animi. Similique nostrum molestiae animi corrupti qui?</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias quis, tempora laborum incidunt qui fuga adipisci doloremque iusto commodi vitae est, nemo iure placeat ut sit optio, consequuntur voluptas impedit.</span><span>Eos officiis, hic esse unde eaque, aut tenetur voluptate quam sint vel exercitationem totam dolor odio soluta illo praesentium non corrupti! Consequuntur velit, mollitia excepturi. Minus, veniam accusantium! Aliquam, ea!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit quis reiciendis veritatis expedita velit vitae amet magni sunt rerum in blanditiis aut tempore quia fugiat, voluptates officia quaerat quam id.</span><span>Sapiente tempore repudiandae, quae doloremque ullam odio quia ea! Impedit atque, ipsa consequatur quis obcaecati voluptas necessitatibus, cupiditate sunt amet ab modi illum inventore, a dolor enim similique architecto est!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque non aliquam, sit illo quas deserunt esse nobis reprehenderit quidem fuga beatae eligendi reiciendis omnis qui repellat velit earum blanditiis possimus.</span><span>Provident aspernatur ducimus, illum beatae debitis vitae non dolorum rem officia nostrum natus accusantium perspiciatis ad soluta maiores praesentium eveniet qui hic quis at quaerat ea perferendis. Ut, aut, natus.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione corrupti quibusdam, sed hic veniam. Perspiciatis ex, quod architecto natus autem totam at commodi excepturi maxime pariatur corporis, veritatis vero, praesentium.</span><span>Nesciunt suscipit, nobis eos perferendis ex quaerat inventore nihil qui magnam saepe rerum velit reiciendis ipsam deleniti ducimus eligendi odio eius minima vero, nisi voluptates amet eaque, iste, labore laudantium.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, voluptas accusantium ad omnis velit distinctio! Adipisci magnam nihil nostrum molestiae rem dolores, ut ad nemo, dolor quos itaque maiores quaerat!</span><span>Quia ad suscipit reprehenderit vitae inventore eius non culpa maiores omnis sit obcaecati vel placeat quibusdam, ipsa exercitationem nam odit, magni nobis. Quam quas, accusamus expedita molestiae asperiores eaque ex?</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum explicabo doloribus nihil iusto quasi vel expedita dignissimos amet mollitia, temporibus aut atque architecto assumenda dolorum nam velit deserunt totam numquam.</span><span>Ab perferendis labore, quae. Quidem architecto quo officia deserunt ea doloribus libero molestias id nisi perferendis eum porro, quibusdam! Odit aliquid placeat rem aut officia minus sit esse eos obcaecati!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi nostrum repellendus placeat, unde aperiam. Fuga, voluptas, minima. Debitis nemo ducimus itaque laboriosam error quaerat reprehenderit quo animi incidunt. Nulla, quis!</span><span>Explicabo assumenda dicta ratione? Tempora commodi asperiores, explicabo doloremque eius quia impedit possimus architecto sit nemo odio eum fuga minima dolor iste mollitia sequi dolorem perspiciatis unde quisquam laborum soluta.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam officia corporis, reiciendis laudantium, voluptate voluptates necessitatibus assumenda, delectus quisquam velit deserunt! Reprehenderit, vel quaerat accusantium nesciunt libero animi. Sequi, eveniet?</span><span>Animi natus pariatur porro, alias, veniam aut est tempora adipisci molestias harum modi cumque assumenda enim! Expedita eveniet autem illum rerum nostrum ipsum alias neque aut, dolorum impedit pariatur non?</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis aliquid rerum, odio veniam ipsam ad officia quos repellat ex aperiam voluptatum optio est animi possimus minus. Sapiente voluptates amet dolorem.</span><span>Illo necessitatibus similique asperiores inventore ut cumque nihil assumenda debitis explicabo rerum, dolorum molestiae culpa accusantium. Nisi doloremque optio provident blanditiis, eum ipsam asperiores, consequatur aliquam vel sit mollitia sunt.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, totam harum perferendis. Minus ea perferendis laboriosam, iste, qui corrupti, quas veritatis omnis officiis animi fuga perspiciatis impedit! Error, harum, voluptas.</span><span>Omnis laborum, cum mollitia facilis ipsa unde distinctio maxime nesciunt illum perspiciatis ut officiis, eligendi numquam dolorem quod modi ipsam est rerum perferendis repellendus totam. Maxime excepturi culpa alias labore.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit deleniti, odit sit consequatur dolorum omnis repellendus, alias vel ullam numquam. Nostrum obcaecati hic, possimus delectus nam atque aliquid explicabo cum.</span><span>Explicabo tenetur minima consequatur, aliquam, laudantium non consequuntur facilis sint, suscipit debitis ex atque mollitia magni quod repellat ratione dolorum excepturi molestiae cumque iusto eos unde? Voluptatum dolores, porro provident!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At laboriosam fuga aperiam eveniet, obcaecati esse, nulla porro iure molestiae praesentium sint fugiat ea voluptate suscipit voluptates mollitia, voluptatibus. Autem, non.</span><span>Numquam velit culpa tempora ratione ipsum minus modi in? Nisi reiciendis, voluptate voluptatem maxime repellat quae odio, repellendus aliquid laborum dolorem. Labore, fuga ea minima explicabo quae voluptatum necessitatibus, similique.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, rerum dolorum nemo error fugiat ut, modi, architecto libero maxime laborum repellendus doloribus neque aperiam adipisci quaerat obcaecati deserunt consequuntur amet!</span><span>Sint, assumenda nisi obcaecati doloremque iste. Perspiciatis accusantium, distinctio impedit cum esse recusandae sunt. Officiis culpa dolore eius, doloribus natus, dolorum excepturi vitae fugiat ullam provident harum! Suscipit, assumenda, harum.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nihil tenetur tempore eligendi qui nesciunt consequatur delectus accusantium consectetur ipsa, nulla doloribus dolores rerum corporis, laborum, laboriosam hic mollitia repellat.</span><span>Ab deleniti vitae blanditiis quod tenetur! Voluptatem temporibus ab eaque quis? Quis odio aliquid harum temporibus totam, ipsa eius iusto fugiat enim in, quibusdam molestiae aliquam consequatur nulla, consequuntur sint.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum odit praesentium quos, earum nesciunt laudantium illo tempora eligendi, porro doloremque mollitia neque aperiam inventore nam maxime dolor labore aspernatur molestias.</span><span>Voluptatibus provident hic cupiditate placeat, ut reprehenderit nisi eum, dolores ad sed quis. Doloribus molestiae, quae rem odit expedita soluta, facilis animi corporis velit ut in, recusandae harum laboriosam veritatis.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt repudiandae molestias magnam delectus veritatis labore, corporis dicta officia quos, ad corrupti odit! Ad hic officia maxime eveniet consectetur similique adipisci!</span><span>Quia at, nesciunt aliquid delectus ex alias voluptas maxime hic esse. Incidunt, laborum quos mollitia dolores et! Voluptas commodi asperiores, fugit quidem quis corporis, a eaque, animi, autem deserunt repellendus.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi quas, voluptas hic minima inventore optio, id quidem placeat necessitatibus omnis voluptatibus vitae mollitia tempora consequuntur consequatur, illo facilis accusamus illum.</span><span>Voluptates consequuntur ipsam odit. Eius quis ipsam vitae, nihil molestias perferendis corporis recusandae consequatur vero iure blanditiis quas adipisci quos voluptatem rem illo voluptate. Eveniet officiis iure sit laborum veniam.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit a quis cumque nostrum quisquam molestiae pariatur, asperiores natus necessitatibus adipisci illum cupiditate nam vero, tempora excepturi laborum, earum. Voluptates, nobis.</span><span>Pariatur suscipit, hic blanditiis libero, iusto, quam cupiditate nam error id asperiores repellat ab consequatur vitae ipsa voluptatem totam magni reiciendis expedita maxime dolor! Minus explicabo quas, laborum ab omnis!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore qui ad assumenda placeat optio illo molestias corporis dolorum cum. Doloribus eius autem obcaecati minima, asperiores iure dignissimos ducimus suscipit dolorem.</span><span>Blanditiis earum accusamus eaque temporibus necessitatibus voluptatum dolorem enim debitis inventore assumenda quae error perspiciatis aut, nulla delectus quam ipsa sapiente ea aliquam laboriosam repudiandae. Nesciunt praesentium, beatae eos quasi!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate dicta voluptate impedit? Ad voluptatum dicta earum perferendis asperiores. Dolore distinctio modi expedita consequatur provident perspiciatis neque totam rerum placeat quas.</span><span>Eveniet optio est possimus iste accusantium ipsum illum. Maiores saepe repudiandae facere, delectus iure dolorem vitae nihil pariatur minima, reprehenderit eligendi dolore impedit, nisi doloribus quidem similique. Optio, delectus, minus.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste ex molestiae architecto enim nihil tempore, atque consequuntur doloribus recusandae sed consequatur veniam quos, in consectetur perspiciatis magni nostrum ab voluptates.</span><span>Nisi quos mollitia quis in maiores asperiores labore deserunt! Voluptate voluptas adipisci qui hic officia molestias, laborum necessitatibus sint nam vel minus incidunt perspiciatis recusandae sunt, rerum suscipit doloremque possimus!</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At nihil perferendis quae quidem facilis aliquid pariatur possimus hic asperiores, recusandae exercitationem adipisci atque laborum, delectus, odit ab reprehenderit distinctio dolor.</span><span>Non excepturi quos aspernatur repudiandae laboriosam, unde molestias, totam, sapiente harum accusamus delectus laborum ipsam velit amet nisi! Consectetur aliquam provident voluptatibus saepe repudiandae eveniet laborum beatae, animi, voluptate dolores.</span></p>
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque magni, eum ipsa, veritatis facere voluptatem dolorum nobis neque minus debitis asperiores iste. Pariatur sequi quam, tempora. Dignissimos, esse similique tempora.</span><span>Ex delectus excepturi autem sunt, nemo repudiandae, recusandae nostrum accusantium nobis temporibus magnam eligendi similique veritatis deleniti, eaque blanditiis possimus at! Repellat alias laboriosam ipsum commodi dolorem, corporis dolore suscipit!</span></p>
```

Comment: Well it is very simple if you take a closer look. Perhaps it is OOP that make it look like it would be bit more complicated than it really is. Other snippets will not include breaking scroll functionality. So I posted something a litle bit more complet. If you don't care about that then my solution can look a bit over the top for your needs. To make it work in FF and IE you just need to add prefix for CSS I think. I will fix it in case anyone else will ask to do so. I added CSS because I wanted to make it "copy/paste" solution. I don't think that this can get any easer than that :-).

Comment: Ok this is not a prefix issue :) but I will fix it anyway.

Comment: Problem solved. It will now work in IE, FF and Chrome... Here what happend: "document.documentElement.scrollTop" Works in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome, 
"document.body.scrollTop" works in Chrome but not in Firefox and not in IE. To fix the issue new method [scrollTop()] was implemented to class prototype. New method returns the value regardles from the browser it work in:
// var curentScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
// return curentScrollTop;

Comment: Another IE bug fixed. classList.add('class1, class2');
will only apply class1, class2 will be ignored, . Fix: classList.add('class1'); classList.add('class2'); Now button is hidden when loading IE.

Answer (score 6):

Easy.

```
var scrollIt = function(time) {
    // time = scroll time in ms
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop,
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var now = Math.min(time,(new Date().getTime())-start)/time;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop
                = document.body.scrollTop = (1-time)/start*scroll;
            if( now == 1) clearTimeout(timer);
        },25);
}
```

Comment: Or just `window.scrollTo(x, y);`.

Comment: That doesn't animate it though.

Comment: I offered an alternative option for `.scrollTop` and `.scrollLeft`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This is only Function that cares about body.scrolltop and documentElement.scrolltop. but there is some errors like scroll never using, miss semi colon etc. Could you please revise it.

Comment: @DenizPorsuk You're right about the "scroll not being used", it was supposed to be `*scroll` when calculating the scroll position. However, I don't see any missing `;`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you are right fot miss semicolon. I could not see var before variable. Here is my function combined with yours. I'm calling your function as callback. But as you see it is jumping I did not understand what is wrong with. http://jsfiddle.net/1avgo1z7/2/

Comment: This solution seems to jump straight to the top?

Answer (score 2):

Just made this javascript only solution below.

Simple usage:

```
EPPZScrollTo.scrollVerticalToElementById('wrapper', 0);
```

Engine object (you can fiddle with filter, fps values):

```
/**
 *
 * Created by Borbás Geri on 12/17/13
 * Copyright (c) 2013 eppz! development, LLC.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */


var EPPZScrollTo =
{
    /**
     * Helpers.
     */
    documentVerticalScrollPosition: function()
    {
        if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset; // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) return document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Internet Explorer 6 (standards mode).
        if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop; // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8.
        return 0; // None of the above.
    },

    viewportHeight: function()
    { return (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat") ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight; },

    documentHeight: function()
    { return (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight; },

    documentMaximumScrollPosition: function()
    { return this.documentHeight() - this.viewportHeight(); },

    elementVerticalClientPositionById: function(id)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        var rectangle = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rectangle.top;
    },

    /**
     * Animation tick.
     */
    scrollVerticalTickToPosition: function(currentPosition, targetPosition)
    {
        var filter = 0.2;
        var fps = 60;
        var difference = parseFloat(targetPosition) - parseFloat(currentPosition);

        // Snap, then stop if arrived.
        var arrived = (Math.abs(difference) <= 0.5);
        if (arrived)
        {
            // Apply target.
            scrollTo(0.0, targetPosition);
            return;
        }

        // Filtered position.
        currentPosition = (parseFloat(currentPosition) * (1.0 - filter)) + (parseFloat(targetPosition) * filter);

        // Apply target.
        scrollTo(0.0, Math.round(currentPosition));

        // Schedule next tick.
        setTimeout("EPPZScrollTo.scrollVerticalTickToPosition("+currentPosition+", "+targetPosition+")", (1000 / fps));
    },

    /**
     * For public use.
     *
     * @param id The id of the element to scroll to.
     * @param padding Top padding to apply above element.
     */
    scrollVerticalToElementById: function(id, padding)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element == null)
        {
            console.warn('Cannot find element with id \''+id+'\'.');
            return;
        }

        var targetPosition = this.documentVerticalScrollPosition() + this.elementVerticalClientPositionById(id) - padding;
        var currentPosition = this.documentVerticalScrollPosition();

        // Clamp.
        var maximumScrollPosition = this.documentMaximumScrollPosition();
        if (targetPosition > maximumScrollPosition) targetPosition = maximumScrollPosition;

        // Start animation.
        this.scrollVerticalTickToPosition(currentPosition, targetPosition);
    }
};
```

Comment: Man, really? Creating this monstrous piece of code is like using rocket launcher to kill a fly.

Comment: @Killah I really care about about simple usage, and readability only. I can post it minified if you want. :)

Comment: What I meant to say is that there are way too many helper functions in there (why do you need a helper function that is used once?), also `console.warn` and string parameter in `setTimeout` are not suitable in production code (the second one is pretty much unsuitable anywhere, since it's `eval` basically).

Comment: Assuming a function call is not an expensive stuff, I prefer extract any code to a named function instead of commenting everything around. So you (me at least) can read code better, also client code can be a shorter ten liner.

Answer (score 2):

Building on some of the answers here, but using some simple math for a smooth transition using a sine curve:

```
scrollTo(element, from, to, duration, currentTime) {
       if (from <= 0) { from = 0;}
       if (to <= 0) { to = 0;}
       if (currentTime>=duration) return;
       let delta = to-from;
       let progress = currentTime / duration * Math.PI / 2;
       let position = delta * (Math.sin(progress));
       setTimeout(() => {
           element.scrollTop = from + position;
           this.scrollTo(element, from, to, duration, currentTime + 10);
       }, 10);
   }
```

Usage:

```
// Smoothly scroll from current position to new position in 1/2 second.
scrollTo(element, element.scrollTop, element.scrollTop + 400, 500, 0);
```

PS. take note of ES6 style

Answer (score 1):

This is a cross browser approach based on answers above

```
function scrollTo(to, duration) {
    if (duration < 0) return;
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var difference = to - scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollTop = scrollTop + perTick;
      document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      if (scrollTop === to) return;
      scrollTo(to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
  }
```

Comment: Nice answer! Can you please explain what's happening with `difference` and `perTick`?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is using [window.scrollBy](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10rozwL5/)

```js
function scroll(pxPerFrame, duration) {
        if (!pxPerFrame || !duration) return;
        const end = new Date().getTime() + duration;
        step(); 

        function step() {
          window.scrollBy(0, pxPerFrame);
          if (new Date().getTime() < end) {
            window.setTimeout(step, 1000 / 60);
          } else {
            console.log('done scrolling'); 
          }
        }
      }
```

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
<button onclick="scroll(-5, 3000)">
scroll(-5, 3000)
</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have choose @akai version of @timwolla answer and added stopAnimation function in return, so before starting new animation, the old one can be stopped.

```
if ( this.stopAnimation )
    this.stopAnimation()

    this.stopAnimation = scrollTo( el, scrollDestination, 300 )


// definitions

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        increment = 20,
        timeOut;

    var animateScroll = function(elapsedTime) {        
        elapsedTime += increment;
        var position = easeInOut(elapsedTime, start, change, duration);                        
        element.scrollTop = position; 
        if (elapsedTime < duration) {
            timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
                animateScroll(elapsedTime);
            }, increment);
        }
    };

    animateScroll(0);

    return stopAnimation

    function stopAnimation() {
        clearTimeout( timeOut )
    }
}

function easeInOut(currentTime, start, change, duration) {
    currentTime /= duration / 2;
    if (currentTime < 1) {
        return change / 2 * currentTime * currentTime + start;
    }
    currentTime -= 1;
    return -change / 2 * (currentTime * (currentTime - 2) - 1) + start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**JS** solution w/o **jQuery**.

```
element.onclick = () => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cross-browser approach based on above solution

```
function doScrollTo(to, duration) {
    var element = document.documentElement;

        var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        increment = 20,
        i = 0;

    var animateScroll = function(elapsedTime) {
        elapsedTime += increment;
        var position = easeInOut(elapsedTime, start, change, duration);
        if (i === 1 && window.scrollY === start) {
            element = document.body;
            start = element.scrollTop;
        }
        element.scrollTop = position;
        if (!i) i++;
        if (elapsedTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                animateScroll(elapsedTime);
            }, increment);
        }
    };

    animateScroll(0);
}
```

The trick is to control the actual scroll change, and if it is zero, change the scroll element.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth scrolling is now implemented by default in all modern browsers.
You can also [polyfill it](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/) for support in older browers.

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll to a certain element
document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position for any element
document.querySelector('.scrollable-element').scrollBy({
  top: 100, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

// Scroll to top
var element = document.querySelector('.scrollable-element');
element.scrollBy({
  top: -element.scrollTop, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score -1):

Linear scrolling animation to bottom. Pure JS, no JQuery. Maybe my solution will be helpful for someone.

```
let action_count = 8;
let speed_ms = 15;
let objDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('js_y5_area3').item(0);

let scroll_height = objDiv.scrollHeight;
let window_height = objDiv.offsetHeight;

let scroll_top = objDiv.scrollTop;
let need_scroll_top = scroll_height - window_height;

if (scroll_top < need_scroll_top)
{
    let step = Math.ceil((need_scroll_top - scroll_top) / action_count);

    let scrollInterval = setInterval(function()
    {
        scroll_top += step;
        objDiv.scrollTop = scroll_top;

        if (scroll_top >= need_scroll_top)
        {
            clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        }

    }, speed_ms);
}
```

You can change variables `action_count`, `speed_ms` to configure scrolling animation on your taste.

Answer (score -2):

Use this solution

```
animate(document.documentElement, 'scrollTop', 0, 200);
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like this is not very cross-browser savvy. :(

Comment: @LucasMorgan you just need to find correct dom element in place for "document.documentElemen", Like whatever suits you

Comment: Unless there is an `animate()` function in the window scope...I think you misunderstand. The `Element.animate()` function is not recognized by many browsers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Comment: Yep I misunderstood. You speak of a jquery function. I assumed you wouldn't bring up jquery since the question asks for no jquery. My bad!

Answer (score -3):

I see that most/all of the above posts search for a button with javascript. This works, as long as you have only one button. I would recommend defining an "onclick" element inside the button. That "onclick" would then call the function causing it to scroll.

If you do it like that, you can use more than one button, as long as the button looks something like this:

```
<button onclick="scrollTo(document.body, 0, 1250)">To the top</button>
```

Comment: This does not animate.