# smooth scroll a div to top just below header

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

How to smoothly scroll a div to top of the page but just below the header.

I have the code in jquery but I need to convert this to pure java-script and should be working in all the latest browsers.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#mydiv"+id).offset().top - 55 }, 699);
```

I got the java script function to scroll but not the animation.

```
document.getElementById('mydiv'+id).scrollIntoView(); scrollBy(0, -55);
```

Can someone help me here , I need to add a small animation to the scroll. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery? If you want it to work in all the latest browsers it sounds like jQuery (or some DOM abstraction library) is the way to go.

Comment: You can use `window.scrollTo()` to scroll without animation if you don't wanna use jquery.

Comment: Check this answer of the animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation

Comment: @KylePlusPlus , I dont want to load the jquery coz of it, its hard to debug through the console.