# JS for smooth scroll to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS to make a smooth scroll from the bottom of the page to the top with this and it works:

```
<script>

     $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
     return true;
  });
</script>
```

But now I want to make a smooth scroll from the top to the bottom, I tried it with this:

```
 <script>

     $("a[href='#footer']").click(function() {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollToBottom: 0 }, "slow");
     return true;
  });
</script>`
```

It doesn't work, it's not a smooth scroll. Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as `scrollToBottom`. Try this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight }, "slow");
```

Comment: what is it like without jquery?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation

Answer (score 58):

With pure JS:

```
 window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

and to the top as:

```
 window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Comment: This should be marked as a valid answer. Thanks!

Comment: Simple and smooth, pure JS without a library and it works in 2022 as well.

Answer (score 3):

For a more comprehensive list of methods for smooth scrolling, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689657/9513184).

---

To scroll to the bottom of the page, the y-position can be set to `document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight`.

For scrolling to a certain position in an exact amount of time, [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can be put to use, calculating the appropriate current position each time. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) can be used to a similar effect when `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported.

```js
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

```js
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  scrollToSmoothly(document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight, 1000);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<button>Scroll to bottom</button>
```

The [SmoothScroll.js library](https://github.com/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll) can be used as well, which handles more complex cases such as smooth scrolling both vertically and horizontally, scrolling inside other container elements, different easing behaviors, scrolling relatively from the current position, and more.

```js
smoothScroll({yPos: 'end', duration: 1000});
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  smoothScroll({yPos: 'end', duration: 1000});
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll@1.2.0/src/smoothscroll.min.js" integrity="sha384-UdJHYJK9eDBy7vML0TvJGlCpvrJhCuOPGTc7tHbA+jHEgCgjWpPbmMvmd/2bzdXU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button>Scroll to bottom</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer and others are correct, but wanted to add another usecase that might help someone.

In some cases, you'd need to do the scrolling inside a `setTimeout()`'s callback with a short delay.

```
function scrollToBottom() {
  window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
}

setTimeout(function() { scrollToBottom(); }, 100);
```

For example: you have a `<button>` which adds a `<div>` element to the bottom of the page when clicked on, and you want to scroll to the bottom so the user can see this new div. In this case, sometimes (depends on the event-loop behavior), you'd need to do the scroll inside a `setTimeout()` because the same action that triggers the scroll actually changes the value of `document.body.scrollHeight`. By delaying it, you make it use the new updated value of `document.body.scrollHeight` after the div was added.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Scroll smoothly to the bottom
domElement.scrollTo({
  top: document.body.scrollHeight,
  behavior: 'smooth',
})
```

All options for `scrollTo` are:

- `top: number`
- `left: number`
- `behavior: 'smooth'` or `behavior: 'auto'`