# Pure Javascript scrollTo with animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollto

I want to covert my code to scroll with animation. A lot of solutions I looked up were functions that had to provide element, etc. I already know exactly the amount I need to scroll down. I just need to animate it.

```
reactScrollTo(nextPos){
    let elem = document.getElementById('ref-'+nextPos);
    let amount = elem.offsetTop+530
    window.scrollTo(0, amount);
}
```

Comment: [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625387/smooth-scrolling-in-javascript/26625940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using React, I would suggest doing your scrolling in a declarative way, instead of manipulating the DOM yourself.

Check out something like [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll).

It allows you to do stuff like:

```
scroll.scrollMore(100)
```

Just pop that in whatever lifecycle event you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do **window scroll** to some specific position then maybe consider use url anchor.
check here [how to use url anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096614/how-to-use-html-anchor-in-a-dynamic-url)

if you try to have "transition" effect while scrolling, then consider use "transform" instead of scrolling.(this is more suitable for scroll inside an element, not window itself)