# Scroll to top button jumps rather than scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, scroll

I couldn't find another thread on this. I have a button that should scroll back up to the top of the page and the same code works on another site. On this site, however, I can't seem to get it to scroll - it just jumps to the top of the page.

Code is:

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn-default").on('click', function() {
        $("HTML, BODY").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: the code is correct, check If your button is a anchor tag and has href="#somethingOrJust#", because that may be causing problem, can you let us know the button html

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation                                                                 Second Link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

> $('html, body').animate({
>       scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top }, 1000);

This will scroll the page down to #target-element over a period of one second (1,000 milliseconds = 1 second).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code it's perfect.Here you use jquery animate function, Please make sure you add JQuery perfectly.
Your can also check you browser console