# How to force page with dynamic AJAX elements to load completely

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to force the following page to load completely:

http://v3.torontomls.net/Live/Pages/Public/Link.aspx?Key=f7aa9fac8a5b45ed9f3baa480373d09a&App=TREB

The problem I am having is that there are dynamix AJAX elements on the page that only load if/when they are scrolled into view.

I have tried using `javascript:window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` but that seems to jump to the end of the page and doesn't load the complete page.

After the page is loaded completely, then I plan to save the document text and do some regex, but I can't begin that until I am certain that all of the page has been scrolled into view and therefore loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
```

You can try on this on any other page. Think it will be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I'm actually trying to run the javascript inside some other software (uBot), so I need to figure out how to get he syntax right, but shouldn't take me too long.

Comment: How would you incorporate your suggestion into this format:      run javascript("javascript:window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: You can't incorporate it into a simple JS command. If you try to do it in plain JS you need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation

Answer (score 0):

actually, you can put the following code:

```
$('.reports').hide();
$('<div id="alldata">').appendTo($('body'));
$('.link-item').each(function(){
    $('<div>').load($(this).attr('data-deferred-loaded')).appendTo($('#alldata'));$(this).remove()
});
```

And now all your data will be loaded, and contained in the div id="alldata"