# Slow down onclick window.scrollBy

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am looking the code for making JavaScript window.scrollBy slower,
but I haven't found anything.
Could some one please advise me how to animate this type of JavaScript scrolling.
And no this link doesn't help me [Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzpa42vw/)

```
<a  onclick="window.scrollBy(0, 300)">Make me slower</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Comment: yes but the button is in the middle of the page, and i want it to scroll 300px down, without any id.

Comment: The demo in the question uses button to execute scrolling animation code. You can take that code and put use it anywhere else in your project.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way to do that but it works fine, is nice and clear:

```
function scrollByRate(y, rate) 
{
  //calculate the scroll height
  var scrolling = Math.max( document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);

  //save the old value as "static" var
  arguments.callee.tmp = arguments.callee.tmp || scrolling + y;

  //make a little scrolling step
  window.scrollBy(0, (arguments.callee.tmp - scrolling) / rate);

  //are we arrived? if no, keep going recursively, else reset the static var
  if(arguments.callee.tmp - scrolling > 100) setTimeout(function() { scrollByRate(y, rate); }, 10);
  else arguments.callee.tmp = undefined;      
}
```

Then your onclick will be like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrollByRate(1000,20)">Scrolling down slowly</a>
```

Try it here

```js
function scrollByRate(y, rate) {
    var scrolling = Math.max( document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
    arguments.callee.tmp = arguments.callee.tmp || scrolling + y;
    window.scrollBy(0, (arguments.callee.tmp - scrolling) / rate);
    if(arguments.callee.tmp - scrolling > 100) setTimeout(function() { scrollByRate(y, rate); }, 10);
    else arguments.callee.tmp = undefined;      
}
```

```css
p {
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrollByRate(500,20)">Scrolling down slowly</a>
</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>e</p>
<p>f</p>
<p>g</p>
<p>h</p>
<p>i</p>
<p>l</p>
```

Read [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/static-variables-methods-decorators) about static var in javascript

Comment: Nice! I forgot about this post :)) great job

Comment: What happens when scrolling reaches bottom of the page? Is it possible to scroll up again then? Did you try?

Comment: This code doesn't work in strict mode due to the use of `arguments.callee`.

Comment: if your problem is arguments.callee try in this way:

`var scrollByRate = function(y, rate) 
{
  var scrolling = Math.max( document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);

  scrollByRate.tmp = scrollByRate.tmp || scrolling + y;

  window.scrollBy(0, (scrollByRate.tmp - scrolling) / rate);

  if(scrollByRate.tmp - scrolling > 100) setTimeout(function() { scrollByRate(y, rate); }, 10);
  else scrollByRate.tmp = undefined;      
}`