# Converting jquery to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and I've been trying to convert it in vanilla javascript. Any pointers please ?

```
 $(".className").click(() => {
                $(".modal").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "normal");
                return false;
            });
```

This is where I've gotten so far by the click. I think it's working fine but the animate is still in jquery

```
document.getElementById("topBtn").onclick = () => {
                $(".modal").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "normal");
                return false;
            };
```

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: Yes I've started with the click conversion but this is as far as I got: document.getElementsByClassName('.className').onclick = function () {

Comment: Obvious point to reproduce jquery's stuff is look at its [sources](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js)

Answer (score 1):

I do this on my website. Use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to deal with scrolling top animation.

Here is a topic about 
[Optimize JavaScript Execution](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution) from google developers.

... when it comes to animation, there are many performance issues to consider. Mayby using animation framework is not a bad idea.

```js
const topBtn =  document.getElementById("topBtn");
const downBtn =  document.getElementById("downBtn");

   
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
   || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
   || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
   || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    
   
topBtn.addEventListener('click', handleTopClick);
downBtn.addEventListener('click', handleDownClick);
function handleDownClick(){
    const currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    scroll(currentPos, 1000, 20); 
 });
}
function handleTopClick(){
    const currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    scroll(currentPos, 0, -20); 
 });
}
// recursive function to scroll 
function scroll(currentPos, targetPos, scrollOffset){
    const distance = currentPos - targetPos;
    const absDistance = Math.abs(distance);
    if (absDistance < scrollOffset) {
      if(absDistance > 0) {
        document.body.scrollTop -= distance;
      }
      return;
    }
    document.body.scrollTop = currentPos + scrollOffset;
 window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
   scroll(currentPos + scrollOffset, targetPos, scrollOffset);
    }); 
}
```

```css
#modal{
  height:1000px;
  background-color:black;
  position:relative;
}
#downBtn{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  font-size:1rem;
}
#topBtn{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <button id="downBtn">down</button>
     <button id="topBtn">top</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1-to-1 conversion for animate, it is in effect its own library. There are plenty of other animation libraries you could use instead, or you could write your own.

There are also [web animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation), which would probably do what you want, but they are not widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some legwork but I'll throw you a bone by giving you some equivalences/things to lookup.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("className") = $(".className")

.addEventListener('event', function(){ /*some code*/ }) = .click(function { /*some code*/ });
```

For the animate part, things get a little trickier. You can scroll using

```
window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos)
```

This method will scroll instantly however and won't animate. There isn't a very concise manner to convert animate to JavaScript like these others. If anyone would like to add a way in the comments feel free.

Answer (score 0):

I got the JS `scrollTo()` function from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation).

The animation utilizes `setTimeout` and the shrinking distance between the `<body>` and the top.

If you are just trying to find an element and you know it's the only one on the page, just use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

To review snippet, please use the "Full page" button.

**Snippet**

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelector('.className');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  scrollTo(document.body, 0, 1000);
});

function scrollTo(ele, to, time) {
  if (time <= 0) return;
  var diff = to - ele.scrollTop;
  var per = diff / time * 10;

  setTimeout(function() {
    ele.scrollTop = ele.scrollTop + per;
    if (ele.scrollTop === to) return;
    scrollTo(ele, to, time - 10);
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the Top</h1>
<p class="instructions">Scroll down to the bottom and click the button</p>


<section>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</section>
<button class="className"><a>Top </a></button>
```