# Javascript - preventDefault scroll to element if its outside the viewport (when pressing tab)

Tags: javascript, scroll, preventdefault

Lets say I have a really big 4500px x 2500px table where each td contains a input-text field.

I have a function which handles scrolling when a field gets focused to 'always' keep the element centered in the viewport (a modified version of [this stackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation/23844067#23844067)).

Is it possible to jump to the next input (default behaviour of tab) but letting my own function scroll to the element.

> e.scrollToElementFocused.preventDefault()

Comment: posting a JS fiddle would help...