# How to make auto scroll to top of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my screen shot :

[image]

My question is how to make it auto scrolling back to top in javascript or any other way ?

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: At least share what have you tried

Comment: `element.scrollTop = 0;` is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery refer this

Comment: If you want to animate it [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8918062/559079)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`element.scrollTop = 0;` will let you get to the element's scroll top:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;

setTimeout(function(){
  el.scrollTop = 0;
}, 500);
```

```css
div{width:200px; height:200px; overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div>
<br>Top-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-<br>-
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Give an id to your div. And then:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('yourdivid');
myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to animate, then try the below

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 2000);
```

If its a div you want to animate,

```
$('#yourid').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1000);
```