# Ionic2 - programmatically scroll an ion-scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having a page with 2 scrollable views next to each other:

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-scroll></ion-scroll>
   <ion-scroll></ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

I want to programmatically scroll the first one, but it seems the scrollTo is only a method on ion-content (which I ofcourse can not scroll, I need to have the second one independant)

Is there any way to solve this?

update: added [a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6Z8tE?p=preview) to show what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are trying to Scroll the Left Scroller and I see you have a view selector called `leftCats`.

So if you just change one line you will be able to scroll. Here is my code below:

**NOTE:** This is just plain javascript. It jumps to the scroll position. You can apply animation if you like later.

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage implements AfterViewChecked {

  @ViewChild('content') content;
  @ViewChild('leftCats') leftItems;

  constructor() {

    }

    scroll() {
      //I want to scroll the left pane here
      console.log('scroll');

      this.leftItems.scrollElement.scrollTop += 50; // Change This Line
    }

}
```

I have also forked it here: [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCzlCfNacPhFHMAZDT4Y?p=preview)

Hope it helps.

Comment: any idea where to start for animating this?

Comment: Found it. For other's reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation