# jQuery scrollTop alternative for react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react app and I was wishing I can render components with a nice animation once the user scrolls down just like how you can do it with jQuery, but I wouldn't use the whole jQuery library just for that.

is there's an alternative for that for react components or even just in normal ES6 Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to trigger scroll animation to a specific element in a page once a trigger button is clicked?

Comment: @KarolisRamanauskas no, a simple fade in or something once they scroll down to that div