# Rewrite jQuery animate to Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I taught myself Vue.js a couple of days ago in the evening and already created my first application yesterday which will soon be used by tens of thousands of users on a daily basis. The original was made with HandleBars and jQuery.

The only thing I couldn't get to work as of yet is the following piece of code:

```
$(".conversation-container").animate({ scrollTop: $(".conversation-container").prop("scrollHeight") }, 10);
```

I tried with the following:

```
var container = this.$el.querySelector(".conversation-container");
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

but unfortunately that didn't provide the same behavior.
Anyone can help me out to accomplish this so I can take jQuery out of the page and go solely Vue.js?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: JQuery animate is basically trying to tween a start and end value over a provided duration. If you want a lightweight tweener, consider using [TweenJS](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js): I've used it with VueJS for JS-dependent animations, and it worked very well ;)

Comment: @Terry I'll take a look into that. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Vucko, it's enterprise software under confidential level hence I can't repro a fiddle.

Comment: @XIII k then. Check [vue2-smooth-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-smooth-scroll), I've used in the past for similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one liner solution to get smooth scroll animations in vanilla JavaScript. If you want pointers on how to attain the same behavior please reference this answer:

[Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)