# jQuery animate() not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll back to top button that brings the user back to the top of the page with a smooth glide. It is working in Firefox but not Chrome:

```
$('a#scroll-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

<a href="#" id="scroll-to-top">Up Top</a>
```

How to get this to work in Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scroll to the top of the page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Comment: @j08691 not quite the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would like to use this code:

```
$('a#scroll-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

​Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZemdY/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use **body** instead of **html** like below:

```
$('a#scroll-to-top').click(function() {
  $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
 }, 500);
  return false;
});
```