# Can a link scroll to the top of a page as well as open a page in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how I can get all my links to scroll to the top of the page as well as open up the desired page in my iframe. Is this possible? I need the link to perform two different functions.

**Alarm Standard**

```
                <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                    // Scroll to top
                                document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

                    // Open up a link in my iframe
                            <A HREF="DocDisplayCategory.cfm?CategoryID=47" TARGET="MainWindow">
                            </A>
                                  } 
                </li>
                </script>
```

Comment: Yes, you can tie multiple actions to an onclick event in javascript.

Comment: Please include some code along with a question... Also are the links being clicked inside the iframe or on the main page?

Comment: The links are being clicked on the main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an event handler.

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction();" >Click Me</a>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        // Scroll to top
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

        // Open up a link in my iframe

        document.getElementById('frame1').src="http://www.foo.com/" 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You may not need to actually scroll to top, `href="#'` will automatically scroll to start of page.

Comment: How would I open up a link using this function?

Comment: What can I put in the function that will make the link display in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

For the scrolling have a look at this here; [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)
To open a link in an iframe  just specify the [`target`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/qt/target-links-iframes-and-frames.htm)

You could event automate the target creation using jquery too.