# jQuery scrollTop syntax error on Firefox 22.0

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I tried to implement the js below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery):

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
return false;
});
```

It just produces an error in the console that I can't seem to remedy.

Comment: What is the _error in the console_ you are getting??

Comment: Well you're missing `});`

Comment: `Sytax Error` then it shows->  `$("html, body").animate(, "slow");`

Comment: without the scrollTop:0 function so I wonder if its deprecated or something similar?

Comment: haha thanks @ExplosionPills but no, I wish it was that simple :D

Comment: Your code is fine. Make sure you add it on document ready. The rest is ok.

Comment: It was a problem with Cache and the CMS I am using storing values incorrectly. Once I cleared cache and fixed the errors, it worked. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix I had to clear cache. You can do this in Firefox with the Web Developers Toolbar or in Chrome in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies some where else in the script.Your Code is working fine after adding `})`.

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `scrollTop: 1000` scrolls down not up. Thanks for the help though.