# How get scroll position after page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've scrolled page downto the middle and then reload page (F5). After that scroll still in the middle. It's normal. My task is to set scrollY = 0 after page loaded.

If I set document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0 (document.body.scrollTop = 0 or window.pageXOffset = 0 and within or out of `$(document).ready(...) or $(window).load(...)` ) page is not scrolled to the top.

I have this function:

```
function getScrollXY() {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
        // Netscape
        x = window.pageXOffset;
        y = window.pageYOffset;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
        // DOM
        x = document.body.scrollLeft;
        y = document.body.scrollTop;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
        // IE6 standards compliant mode
        x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return [x, y];
}
```

It always return x=0 even if page is scrolled after page was loaded.

So how to set scroll to top after page loaded?

The code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g6w9r/1/

The frame from jsfiddle to see the result:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/g6w9r/1/show/

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle we can debug?

Comment: Yes, sure. I added links

Comment: That is strange. I tried it in safari - scrolled that also. But this is what I have in chrome (1. after direct load page, 2. after F5 pressed) http://screencast.com/t/jsLkiYKDfB