# ScrollTo() method not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to use scrollTo() for making a div become fixed after it touches the top on scrolling. here is the full html with script I added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .topnav{
                width:100%; 
                background-color:#444; 
                color:#eee; 
                padding:10px; 
                position:relative;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(window).scroll(function(){

                if($('body').scrollTo('.topnav', {offsetTop : '0'})){

                    $(this).css('position','fixed');
                    $(this).css('top','0');

                } else {

                    $(this).css('position','relative');
                }
            });
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>sdsf
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

        <div class="topnav">topnav</div>

        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>dfgv<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

    </body>
</html>
```

but it is not working at all. my logic was to say thjat if the div scrolls to top at 0 position, its position should change from relative to fixed, so that it fixes at the top after that.
please tell what i did wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery it should be help you

Comment: There's no `scrollTo()` in jQuery API. Do you mean `scrollTop()`?

Comment: window.scrollTo(x,y) is function not only scrollTo.

Comment: you have not included the scrollTo library

Comment: I don't see you're using plugin.  Yet I would like to know, whether you're using any plugin (scrollTo)?

Answer (score 0):

After a little investigation, it is clear that **you're missing to add [scrollTo()](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin**.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js' />
```

Add this to your code.

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnRM8/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between `scrollTop()` and `scrollTo()`.
**scrollTop()** : method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements.
**scrollTo()**  :   method scrolls the content to the specified coordinates.

See it here working, http://jsfiddle.net/cryostat/UhmNb/.

To make a div fixed when it touches the top, use this:

```
var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
            fixed = true;
            $('#nav').css({position:'fixed',top:0});
        }
    } else {
        if( fixed ) {
            fixed = false;
            $('#nav').css({position:'static'});
        }
    }
});
```

For a good example see [this](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/).