# Scroll to the top of the page without refreshing/reloading of that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a mobile website. This website was mostly viewed in Opera mini and UCbrowser. I have added scroll to top button as

```
<input type="button" name="scroll to top" onclick="scroll(0,0)"/>
```

but this on click it reloads and then goes to the top. some times, it doesn't work..

for details go to feinix.org/mevents.php in opera mini and ucbrowser

view m.facebook.com in opera mini they have added [ ↑ ] Top. it would be great if someone post me the code behind that

Comment: try `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` [How do I scroll to the top of the page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Comment: try `$(selector).scrollTop(0)`

Comment: try preventDefault before scroll(0,0). Like so: `document.querySelector("<selector>").addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); window.scroll(0,0); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Jquery

```
 $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 200);
```

or using simple Html Anchors like this

```
 //Add this to your top of your page
 <a id="tips"></a>

 //Show this as your button with css
 <a href="#tips">Scroll to top</a>
```

Comment: thanks and i personally like jquery because it gives smooth animation going top.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```