# Make AngularJS jump to top of page on navigation

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and can't figure out how to make Angular jump to the top of the page when navigating around my site.

I've read about, and tried implementing a few methods but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery).  As the selected Answer is pure `JS`, you can use it in `AngularJS` too.

Comment: could you define anchors and link to those (if you don't need the animation)?

Comment: Where would you put that? It doesn't work in the controller