# How to scroll the div content using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

I want to scroll the div, containing the text, to the top when I mouseover the up arrow and stop when the mouse leaves the focus. Same for the down arrow.
I tried using jquery but it fails.

please visit: http://jsfiddle.net/shantanubhaware/38WMF/12/

Here is Html code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="news event">
        <div class="up arrow nav"></div>
        <div class="down arrow nav"></div>
        <p class="content items"> <span class="p">text1
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            text2
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            text3
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                text4</span>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use the following jquery

```
$('.up').mouseover(function () {
    scrollToTop();
});
$('.down').mouseover(function () {
    scrollToBottom();
});

function scrollToTop() {

    var cur = $('.content').scrollTop();
    while (cur > 0) {
        cur = parseInt(cur) - 50;
        $('.content').animate({
            scrollTop: cur
        }, 800);
    }
}

function scrollToBottom() {

    var cur = $('.content').scrollTop();
    var height = $('.p').height();
    while (cur < height) {
        cur = parseInt(cur) + 50;
        $('.content').animate({
            scrollTop: cur
        }, 800);
    }

}
```

tell me if i am wrong anywhere or if i want to use any other technique.
Thanks for your support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scroll to the top of the page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to stop the ongoing animation before starting a new one, otherwise it will finish the ongoing animation first and **only then** will start the new one.

its done by calling `.stop()` first.

also you forgot to bind on mouse leave events.

heres yours fixed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/38WMF/14/