# Scroll p:messages into view when it is updated and (error) messages are present

Tags: primefaces, scroll

I am working with PrimeFaces messages, I want my whole page to scroll to top when `p:messages` is rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Deprecated with PrimeFaces < 6.2**

In you backing bean (that one which produces the messages), you should know when you render a `p:message`. If so simply execute this:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.scrollTo(0,0);");
```

**Update:**

With the [newer PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) versions (>= 6.2), the approach to execute Javascript on the client side is (by using *x* and *y* coordinates):

```
PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
instance.execute("window.scrollTo(0,0);");
```

To scroll to an *element* use the element's clientId:

```
PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
instance.scrollTo("myElementsClientId");
```

Find more information here:

- http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/window.htm#scroll_to
- examples with jQuery for smooth scrolling as well: [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Comment: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.scrollTo(0,0);"); is deprecated. Use PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0);"); instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but your script is only partially correct. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Assign an ID to your p:message component

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" id="myMessage" />
```

Then, in your backing bean call RequestContext.scrollTo method:

- in PrimeFaces >= 6.0:

  ```
  PrimeFaces.current().scrollTo("myMessage")
  ```
- in Primefaces < 6.0:

  ```
  RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context.scrollTo("myMessage");
  ```

  which is deprecated in PrimeFaces 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that your button is causing the messages to appear.

***XHTML***

```html
<p:commandButton value="Save" 
                 oncomplete="scrollToFirstMessage()" />
```

***javascript***

```javascript
//javascript function which scroll to the first message in page   
function scrollToFirstMessage() {
     try {
        PrimeFaces.scrollTo($('.ui-message :first-child').eq(0).parent().attr('id'));
     } catch(err) {
       //No Message was found!
     }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Javascript could also look like this:
`$('.ui-messages :first-child').eq(0).parent()[0].scrollIntoView();`
Just JS + jQuery.

Comment: I'm not a jQuery expert. Could you explain what the query, `eq(0).parent.attr('id')` stands for in details, please (ideally not in a comment, but in the answer)?

Answer (score 1):

There are valid answers already that show how to scroll to the `p:messages` component, but they all require you to execute code in a backing bean. This requires you to do / call the same in each action. None show how to scroll to the messages component when it is rendered (updated).

You can implement a [phase listener](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/phaselistener/info) and check messages are present and if the messages component's `clientId` is present in the [`PartialViewContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html) `renderIds`:

> These client identifiers are used to identify components that will be processed during the render phase of the request processing lifecycle.

Your listener can look something like this:

```
public class MessagesUpdateListener implements PhaseListener {

  private final String MESSAGES_ID = "yourMessagesClientId";

  @Override
  public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    // Empty
  }

  @Override
  public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (!fc.getMessageList().isEmpty() &&
        fc.getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().contains(MESSAGES_ID)) {
      RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().scrollTo(MESSAGES_ID);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
  }

}
```

Make sure to register it in your `faces-config.xml`:

```
<lifecycle>
  <phase-listener>your.MessagesUpdateListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Tested with XHTML:

```
<h:form id="main">

  <p:messages id="messages" />
  <p:inputText id="text1" required="true" />

  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>
  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>
  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>
  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>
  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>
  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>
  this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>this<br/>is<br/>a<br/>long<br/>page<br/>

  <p:commandButton value="Update" update="messages text1"/>
  <p:commandButton value="No update"/>

</h:form>
```

To check for global messages, use:

```
fc.getMessageList(null).isEmpty()
```

See also:

- [Add global message when field validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247737/add-global-message-when-field-validation-fails)

Comment: Creative... had me  thinking... You could also add a passtrough attribute to the `p:messages` like `scrollToWhenDisplayed` and override a small part of the PrimeFaces messages component and in it check for the presence of the scrollToWhenDisplayed and if present scroll to it. No need for a phaselistener then and no need to know the id of the component in it...