# Animate Scrolling to the Top

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, blogger

sorry for reposting this question, I don't think I was clear in my other post.

I want to make a scroll to the top animation link, like the link at the bottom of this website, http://www.thechrisellefactor.com/

How would I go about doing/code this? I don't have much experience in coding just as a heads up, I'm learning as I go :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this post

[Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <button>Return To TOP</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate and set how long the scroll takes you can do it like this

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/bskxrkfr/) showing it in action