# How to scroll an element to its starting point

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a website where I need to scroll the user to the top of the page (with jQuery) after form submit, everything works except for the actual scrolling, I believe the reasoning for this is that the person before wrote the entire page in `<tables>` and the table element is scrolling, not the body. So standard soutions like:

```
$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
```

are not working, as they do not scroll the table/form to its starting point. Does anyone have a solution to this(other than tweaking the table not scroll on overflow)?

Comment: Does this apply?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt ive tried that, i dont need to scroll to the top of a page per say, i need to scroll a tables whos overflow was handled as scroll to the top (its original starting position)

Comment: Try this: `$('*').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);` - This will scroll whatever is there to scroll :)

Comment: @LcSalazar man, that's so dirty. But it worked! Put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: that's ultra-dirty, you should invest some minutes in finding out the only element that has scrolled, instead of setting up hundreds of animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to target every element with the selector `*`, and then apply the animation to those:

```
$('*').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
```