# Foundation Reveal issue in firefox

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation framework. When I scroll down to the page `in firefox` and open the Reveal result in gray overlay only here i need to scroll to the top by myself to see the Reveal. I added this `CSS` to the model.

```
#id-of-the-reveal-element {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px !important;
}
```

This is working fine but the `slideDown` and `slideUp` not working as normal instead it will just `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` in both Firefox and Chrome. What is the solution for this issue to get the normal behavior of the Reval as in Chrome.

Comment: First, check that you use last update of jquery. Also I hope this link will be helpful for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery)

Comment: Can you put your code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look here, at Ken Smith's Post](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/21450-reveal-modal-positioning-and-background-issues)

By adding `onclick="javascript: location.hash='#page'; location.hash='';"` to the button/link that opens modal it will automatically scroll for you.

**Just replace #page with your modal id.**

Unfortunately this is only a temporary workaround. Hope it helps though!

Answer (score 0):

comment out your CSS...

```
#id-of-the-reveal-element {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px !important;
}
```

whenever foundation reveal js tries to position its modal box on the center of the screen or the place you trigger the modal box, your CSS forces it to display 100px from top of the page with fixed position.
else you could post your code (structure) of the triggering part and the reveal modal box so that I could get a clear idea.

Comment: did the above answer helpful? if no, please let me know.