# How to change visitors location on page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to have a button, and when you click on it, it will get you (the visitor) to the top of the page. 
How can this be done?
Thanks

Comment: I want the peace in the world. How can this be done ?

Comment: <div id='PageTop'></div> then else where on the page <a href='#PageTop'>Top of Page</a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Alexis: Excellent comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a keyboard attached:

Press the `'Home'` button.

Answer (score 2):

The classic operation of hyperlinks is to point to a page different from the one being viewed, to navigate the site. It is also possible to create a link to a specific location on the current page, or to another page in order to position the browser correctly.

Creating an anchor is easy: you just have to assign the element to which you want to be able to point an identifier (with the attribute HTML id) and to associate a link starting with the character #, followed by the name of this Identifier.

```
Ex: 
<div id="top">...</div>

It is then enough to make a link to this anchor:
<a href="#top">top of page</a>

Demo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>top link</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="top">...</div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <!-- Content -->
        <!-- Content -->

        <a href="#top">top of page</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you add some description to the code please :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it like this** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery Back To Top Button by CodexWorld</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">             </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $(window).scroll(function(){ 
       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
        $('#scroll').fadeIn(); 
       } else { 
        $('#scroll').fadeOut(); 
      } 
     }); 
    $('#scroll').click(function(){ 
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); 
     return false; 
    }); 
  });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">
/* BackToTop button css */
#scroll {
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#3498db;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  display:none;
  -webkit-border-radius:60px;
  -moz-border-radius:60px;
  border-radius:60px
  }
  #scroll span {
   position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-8px;
  margin-top:-12px;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  border:8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color:#ffffff
 }
 #scroll:hover {
  background-color:#e74c3c;
  opacity:1;filter:"alpha(opacity=100)";
  -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=100)";
 }
</style>
</head>

 <body>
   <!-- BackToTop Button -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="scroll" title="Scroll to Top" style="display: inline;">Top<span></span></a>

     <!-- ++++++++++++ Page Content Goes Here ++++++++++++ -->

    </body>
   </html>
```

> Just Copy & Paste the script and run

Answer (score 1):

On button click, run the Javascript:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a link:

```
<a href="#">Back to top</a>
```

With button:

```
<a href="#">
    <button>Back to top</button>
</a>
```

See also:

[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

[HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)