# Scroll to top - when going to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to fix so that when i press on a link on my website the new "page" will open at the top.

Trided something like this:

```
$(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < ($(".pageWrapper").offset().top - 110)) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".pageWrapper").offset().top - 110 }, 2000);
                }
            });
```

But didn't rlly work.

Any ideas? ... haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Alright try this

```
$(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop : 0   // 0 means top,change it to 110 for offset                  
  }, 500);
});
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

this s pure js solution you can choose any one

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

or

you almost got it - you need to set the scroll Top on body, not window:

```
$(function() {
   $('body').scrollTop(0);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({ 
         scrollTop: 0
     }, 2000);
  return false
 });
```