# Javascript Scrolling all the way up in Google Hangouts

Tags: javascript, scroll, google-hangouts

How can I scroll all the way up to the beginning of the chat in Google Hangouts?

I tried `window.scrollTo(0,0);` and some other things but they don't seem to work.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: i am using chrome 60

Comment: i have looked at that question before but those solutions do not seem to work in console

Comment: I suppose you can't, since when opening a Hangouts window, there's only a small part of the conversation shown in the "window", and when you scroll up, more content is lazy-loaded to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: it is returning an object in console but not going to the top