# How do I scroll to the top of a page on a button click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll to the top of the page when I click on a button. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer. Somewhere in OnClick function I had to put this:

`this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#trip-request-s‌​tep-' + index ).scrollIntoView();`

Where #trip-request-step is the id element from the page where I want to navigate.

Answer (score 3):

You can call this inside the button click event

```
goTop(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It is not working. I have a frame with scroll bar in the right of the page.

Comment: This was the answer. Somewhere in OnClick function I had to put this:    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#trip-request-step-' + index ).scrollIntoView(); Where #trip-request-step is the id element from the page where I want to navigate.