# R Shiny Dashboard Scroll to Top on Button Click

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there any way to scroll to the top of the page in ShinyDashboard on a button click?

I've added the following lines in `ui.R` under `dashboardSidebar(` :

```
useShinyjs(), 
extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.button = function() {document.body.scrollTop = 0;}"),
```

and the following in `server.R` under `observeEvent(input$button, {`:

`js$button()`

This seems to work in the app preview in RStudio, but not in browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the [first Google hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery) for "javascript scroll to top", the most upvoted answer is `window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);`

I tried replacing your `document.body.scrollTop = 0;` with `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` and it worked.

FYI, if you only have that one very simple function to define, you can also get away with `shinyjs::runjs("window.scrollTo(0, 50)")` in the server code