# How to scroll page up from commandButtom Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to scroll my page up from commandButtom.

```
<p:commandButton id="search"
                             update="contentForm:campaignListcontentForm:noResults"
                             icon="fa fa-search"
                             value="#{messages.labelSearch()}"
                             styleClass="btn-search"
                             actionListener="#{marketingCampaignBean.setTrueClearEntityModel()}"/>
```

and my dataScroller

```
<p:dataScroller id="campaignList"
                                                value="#{marketingCampaignBean.entityModel}"
                                                var="marketingCampaign"
                                                lazy="true"
                                                chunkSize="21">
```

I used JS `onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0);` it´s working, but i can´t use it in my project.

I' using primefaces 6.2 in a xhtml file using jsf. The above option feels slugish and i wouldn´t want to go that route.

Comment: What's the problem about the working solution? We have more suggestions here btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Yes. You said that.

Comment: Why not??? Weird...

Comment: They said that I can not solve the problem in this way, I have to find another way.

Comment: Try with `oncomplete` instead of `onclick`

Comment: The best solution I´ve found  is  "onstart="cleanScroller()"