# Scroll table at top on adding a new row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html, bootstrap-4

I am new to the `web Development.` Here I have a table, in that table,

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, it has a scrollbar as it has a fixed height. Now, I have 50 `tr` in that table, So, user is scrolling that table .
Now, I have a button on click of that one more gets added it gets added in the `first position`.
SO, user has scrolled the table, and the also gets added. Now, what I want to do is as soon as row gets added , the `scroll bar should be at top`
 so that user will immediately see the newly added row.

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You'll find what you need (and probably more) in [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: So, here is widnow that means it will be for the browsers right. what abouy the tabel ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [antd](https://ant.design/components/form/) library made for react to implement it.

In it specifically, you can use prop validateFieldsAndScroll.
For example in your case your handleSubmit function will be something like:

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Element.scrollTo function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo)
e.g.

```
document.querySelector('tbody').scrollTo(0, 0)
```

EDIT:

The React way would be something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody ref={ref=>this.tbody = ref}>
      ...
```

and then in an onClick handler:

```
onClick() {
  // add the new row
  const rowsWithNewRow = ...
  this.setState({rows:rowsWithNewRow})
  this.tbody.scrollTo(0,0)
  ...
```

Comment: Actually , in this app I am not using document anywhere. So, and also not jquery.

Comment: I am trying to do in a react way

Comment: @ganesh Note, `document.querySelector` is not jQuery, it is plain javascript