# How to get my form to start from the top of the page? keeps scrolling to the bottom whenever 'next' button is clicked

Tags: html

I have a form with multiple pages. The first page is ok, it starts up at the top. whenever I hit the next button, the form goes to the next page but it starts from the bottom and you have to scroll up which gets annoying. How can I set the form to start on top every time the next page is hit? https://jsfiddle.net/uz5exL6j/

```
<form id="regForm"  action="https://formspree.io/mn@gmail.com" method="POST">
  <!-- <h1>Event Application</h1> -->
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
    <H3 id="subhead">CONTACT INFORMATION</H3>
    <label><label id="required">*</label>Primary Contact Name:</label>
    <p><input  required placeholder="First Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="First-Name"></p>
    <p><input  required placeholder="Last Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Last-Name"></p>
    <p>Primary Contact Title:<input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Primary-Title"></p>
    <p>Alternate Contact Name<input  placeholder="First Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Alt-Contact-FName"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Alt-Contact-LName"></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I was thinking maybe to just have the CSS reset every time? but idk if that would do it?

Comment: Css doesn't give you the power over the scroll, since you already using JavaScript why not use it to scroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of next, add

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

So your page always scroll to top when user will click on next button

Comment: <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button> so just add it to this line?

Comment: @Abigail put @Vikas's code at the top of your `showTab` function and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you place an ID in an anchor tag, the new page will position itself at the top of that anchor tag.

For example:

```
<a href="my_next_page#regForm">Next</a>
```

Will navigate to the `my_next_page.html` page, and position itself with the element having an `id="regForm"` at the top of the page.

For example, the ID of the div containing this answer is: `id="answer-56532070"`

Click on the below link and see how the new page is positioned with this answer right at the top of the page:

(Hover over the link first and observe the full link in the bottom left of the browser)

[Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532021/how-to-get-my-form-to-start-from-the-top-of-the-page-keeps-scrolling-to-the-bot#answer-56532133)