# Scroll to page top using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the existing script that I am using to filter some product details in my page.
Currently, on filtering it loads a "loading" GIF animation.
Instead of that I want it to scroll to the top using simple div id function.
consider the page URL is http://websitename.com/folder/index.php,
I am able to scroll to the top using

```
<a href="#top" class="nav-link">Go to top</a>
```

How can I automatically scroll to the top by changing this JQuery script ?
I want to use this function instead of `<div id="loading" style="" ></div>`, how can I do that ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
        var ram = get_filter('ram');
        var storage = get_filter('storage');
.....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript)

Comment: window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);

Comment: @Bryn, Thank You.       $('.filter_data').html(window.scrollTo(1000, 0)); worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bryn  `. $('.filter_data').html(window.scrollTo(1000, 0));` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$("a[href='#top']").on('click', function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
```

(or even $('.filter_data').html(window.scrollTo(1000, 0)); )

You should be able to just use

```
window.scrollTo(1000, 0);
```