# How to scroll to top of page on Button Click using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component with a section tag with an id and ref of `map`. The id is used to load a Google Map, don't worry about this.

```
<section
    id="map"
    ref="map"
>
</section>
```

I have a function called `showUserLocationOnTheMap()` with a button called `Map` that's invoked when a User clicks on it. This function shows a marker on the map based on an address, that is stored in the db from a previous step.

```
showUserLocationOnTheMap(latitude, longitude) {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom:15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {

        const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        infoWindow.setContent(
            `<div class="ui header">
                <h6>company name</h6>
             </div>
              `
        );
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    });

    this.$refs.map.scrollToTop();

},
```

```
<button
    @click="showUserLocationOnTheMap(item.profile.latitude,item.profile.longitude)"
    class="apply-job-btn btn btn-radius btn-primary apply-it"
>
    Map
</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is, I have a bunch of search results, so when someone is scrolling far down the page and they click the map button from the record, it will do two things.

1. It shows a marker on the map (This is working)
2. It scrolls back up to the top of the page so the User can see the Map with the marker on it.

**WHAT I TRIED:**
I created this function below:

```
scrollToTop() {
    this.$el.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

I added a ref attribute called map to my Section tag and then at the end of my `showUserLocationOnTheMap()` function I called this line (as you can also see above).
`this.$refs.map.scrollToTop();`

The problem is I'm getting this error:
`Cannot read property 'scrollToTop' of undefined"`

Comment: To scroll to the top of the page, you can use `document.body.scrollIntoView()`. Not sure if it fits wat you want.

Comment: please provide the structure if your components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript)

Comment: #Keith Nicholas This isn't working:
scrollToTop() {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }

Comment: #Seblor This isn't working and returning no errors:
scrollToTop() {
                document.body.scrollIntoView();
            }

Comment: You can try this.. const router = new Router({
   .....
    scrollBehavior() {
        document.getElementById('app').scrollIntoView();
    }
})  together with what you have

Comment: I'm getting this error, even though I'm importing my router file.
Unresolved type Router
I put your code in my SearchComponent.vue is that the right place?