# scroll dyrect to top of the page in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have used onclick event

```
    scrolltoTop= async () => {
        window.scrollTo(0,0)
     }
```

but it takes more time to go top so how to go top dyrect using javascript,
and if it is not support than how to fast scroll?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to the top of the page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.scrollTo(xCoord, yCoord);` you can use `scrollIntoView()` like so:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="top"></div>
   .....
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  document.getElementById("top").scrollIntoView();
</script>
```