# How do I make the page scroll to bottom (JS) after a message is appended to the chat window?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a chatbot that should eb scrolling to the bottom of the page every time a new message is added to the chatHistory element. I've used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page) page but the scroll won't work.

Not sure if the issue is becasue chatHistory is not the correct scrollable element, but I've also tried calling chat-container (via getElementsByClassName('.chat-container')) in the scrollToBottom() function and it still doesn't work.

Using

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    window.scrollTo({
        left: 0,
        top: document.body.scrollHeight,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
};
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript) also doesn't work

Here's my html+JS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling for the whole page */
        }

        h1, h2, h3 {
            text-align: center; /* Centering the titles */

        }

        .header-container {
            position: fixed;
            width: 90%;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%; /* Set left to 50% of the viewport width */
            transform: translateX(-50%); /* Move the header back to the left by half of its own width */
            background-color: #fff;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        .chat-container {
            margin: 70px auto 5px; /* Adjust this value based on the header's actual height */
            width: 45%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            overflow-y: auto; 
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 100px; /* Initial bottom padding */
            border: 0px solid #969696;
        }

        #chatHistory {
            width: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;
            border: 0px solid #969696;
            padding: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            word-wrap: break-word; /* Ensure long words are wrapped */
        }

[...]

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-container">
        <h3><u>header</u></h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="chat-container"><!--</div> id="chatContainer">-->
        <div id="chatHistory"></div> <!-- Chat history will be displayed here -->
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
        <textarea id="userInput" placeholder="Ask something..." oninput="autoGrowTextArea(this)"></textarea>
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">&#x2B06;</button> <!-- Unicode up-pointing arrow -->
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('userInput').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                e.preventDefault();
                sendMessage();
            }
        });

        function autoGrowTextArea(textArea) {
            textArea.style.height = 'auto';
            var maxHeight = 120; // Max height for 7.5 lines of text
            textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight > maxHeight ? `${maxHeight}px` : `${textArea.scrollHeight}px`;
            adjustChatContainerHeight();
        }

        function adjustChatContainerHeight() {
            const inputContainerHeight = document.querySelector('.input-container').offsetHeight;
            const chatContainer = document.getElementById('chatContainer');
            chatContainer.style.paddingBottom = `${inputContainerHeight + 20}px`;
        }

        function scrollToBottom() {
                const chatHistory = document.getElementById('chatHistory');
                chatHistory.scrollTop = chatHistory.scrollHeight;
            };

        function appendMessageToHistory(role, message) {
            const chatHistory = document.getElementById('chatHistory');
            const messageElement = document.createElement('p');
            messageElement.textContent = `${role}: ${message}`;
            chatHistory.appendChild(messageElement);
            scrollToBottom();
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
            appendMessageToHistory('You', userInput);
            fetch('/chat', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ message: userInput }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                appendMessageToHistory('Bot', data.response || 'Error: No response'); // Append bot response to history
                document.getElementById('userInput').style.height = '20px'; // Reset textarea height
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

            // Clear input field after sending the message
            document.getElementById('userInput').value = '';
        }

        // Initial adjustment and scroll when the page loads
        window.onload = function() {
            adjustChatContainerHeight();
            scrollToBottom();
        };

        // Adjust and scroll when window is resized
        window.onresize = function() {
            adjustChatContainerHeight();
            scrollToBottom();
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Your overflow is occurring on `body`, so you should auto scroll that. As a test, simply add `overflow:hidden` to body and you'll see what's going on. Likely you'd want to make a wrapper around the entire chat experience (both history and input areas), probably need some `height:100%`'s too.

Comment: For further reference, I would check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 2):

The code you've provided seems to be throwing further errors, but I was able to fix the issue brought up in your question by using the following:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Check out the below code snippet to see it in action:

```js
document.getElementById('userInput').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendMessage();
  }
});

function autoGrowTextArea(textArea) {
  textArea.style.height = 'auto';
  var maxHeight = 120; // Max height for 7.5 lines of text
  textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight > maxHeight ? `${maxHeight}px` : `${textArea.scrollHeight}px`;
  adjustChatContainerHeight();
}

function adjustChatContainerHeight() {
  const inputContainerHeight = document.querySelector('.input-container').offsetHeight;
  const chatContainer = document.getElementById('chatContainer');
  chatContainer.style.paddingBottom = `${inputContainerHeight + 20}px`;
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
};

function appendMessageToHistory(role, message) {
  const chatHistory = document.getElementById('chatHistory');
  const messageElement = document.createElement('p');
  messageElement.textContent = `${role}: ${message}`;
  chatHistory.appendChild(messageElement);
  scrollToBottom();
}

function sendMessage() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  appendMessageToHistory('You', userInput);
  fetch('/chat', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: userInput
      }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      appendMessageToHistory('Bot', data.response || 'Error: No response'); // Append bot response to history
      document.getElementById('userInput').style.height = '20px'; // Reset textarea height
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

  // Clear input field after sending the message
  document.getElementById('userInput').value = '';
}

// Initial adjustment and scroll when the page loads
window.onload = function() {
  adjustChatContainerHeight();
  scrollToBottom();
};

// Adjust and scroll when window is resized
window.onresize = function() {
  adjustChatContainerHeight();
  scrollToBottom();
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.header-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.chat-container {
  margin: 70px auto 5px;
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border: 0px solid #969696;
}

#chatHistory {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 0px solid #969696;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-container">
    <h3><u>header</u></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="chat-container">
    <div id="chatHistory"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <textarea id="userInput" placeholder="Ask something..." oninput="autoGrowTextArea(this)"></textarea>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">&#x2B06;</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```